# Convert special characters to HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert special characters to HTML in JavaScript?

Example:

- `&` (ampersand) becomes `&amp`.
- `"` (double quote) becomes `&quot` when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not set.
- `'` (single quote) becomes `&#039` only when `ENT_QUOTES` is set.
- `<` (less than) becomes `&lt`.
- `>` (greater than) becomes `&gt`.

Comment: See JavaScript htmlentities http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064

Comment: You can use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need a function that does something like

```
return mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

But taking into account your desire for different handling of single/double quotes.

Comment: what does the slash g do?

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle `/g` in a regular expression means "global". Simply put, all occurrences of the string will be replaced. Without `/g` only the first match would be replaced.

Comment: A better answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/4835406/7514010

Answer (score 226):

The best way in my opinion is to use the browser's inbuilt HTML escape functionality to handle many of the cases. To do this simply create a element in the DOM tree and set the `innerText` of the element to your string. Then retrieve the `innerHTML` of the element. The browser will return an HTML encoded string.

```
function HtmlEncode(s)
{
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  return s;
}
```

Test run:

```
alert(HtmlEncode('&;\'><"'));
```

Output:

```
&amp;;'&gt;&lt;"
```

This method of escaping HTML is also used by the [Prototype JS library](http://www.prototypejs.org/) though differently from the simplistic sample I have given.

Note: You will still need to escape quotes (double and single) yourself. You can use any of the methods outlined by others here.

Comment: note that `delete el` is a mistake here. http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me when I try it. I get the characters back unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with odd characters, plus Chrome is sneaky and doesn't show you the real HTML output, but Firebug does (actually it showed an html entity for the copyright symbol when the generated source doesn't encode it). This does work fine on `<>&` but isn't as all encompassing as Neotropic's or KooiInc's solutions.

Comment: with jQuery, `output = $('<div>').text(input).html()`

Comment: Both methods does not convert ' into &apos; and " into &quot; So it still can be used for XSS attacks.

Comment: This also works the other way around if you're trying to parse html, but I'd suggest parsing and replacing each character escape sequence individually rather than the all the html at once to prevent XSS

Comment: @BeauCielBleu How is this vulnerable to XSS injection if the string is always treated as text? how would the browser ever consider it html?

Comment: Everything looks fine, but this doesn't convert spaces to &nbsp; , so in case of multi spaces you will see just one space in HTML. Add this `s = s.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');` line after `s = el.innerHTML;` and it will solve the problem.

Comment: @dragon very cool and also reversible: `input = $('<div>').html(output).text()` (I wonder how to do this without jQuery this simply)

Comment: I think @Somebody confused encoding to html with encoding to an html attribute value

Answer (score 44):

For those who want to **decode** an integer char code like `&#xxx;` inside a string, use this function:

```js
function decodeHtmlCharCodes(str) { 
  return str.replace(/(&#(\d+);)/g, function(match, capture, charCode) {
    return String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  });
}

// Will output "The show that gained int’l reputation’!"
console.log(decodeHtmlCharCodes('The show that gained int&#8217;l reputation&#8217;!'));
```

### ES6

```js
const decodeHtmlCharCodes = str => 
  str.replace(/(&#(\d+);)/g, (match, capture, charCode) => 
    String.fromCharCode(charCode));

// Will output "The show that gained int’l reputation’!"
console.log(decodeHtmlCharCodes('The show that gained int&#8217;l reputation&#8217;!'));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this will decode everything.

Comment: Note that this only decodes integer char codes.  It won't decode something like &amp; or &gt;

Comment: @Magmatic the opening line of "*For those who want to decode an integer char code like `&#xxx;` inside a string*" is clear enough to indicate that these functions are for decoding **integer** encodings; if you want to decode *named* encodings, there are plenty of other functions here to do that.

Answer (score 36):

[**edit 2023**] Support unicode [surrogate pairs](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#:%7E:text=Surrogate%20pairs&text=The%20first%20code%20unit%20of,surrogate%20or%20a%20trail%20surrogate.) (use `String.codePointAt`).

This generic function encodes every nonalphabetic character to its HTML code ([numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) (NCR)):

```js
const strEncoded =  HTMLEncode(`&Hellõ Wórld `);
document.querySelector(`div`).innerHTML = strEncoded;
console.log(strEncoded);

function HTMLEncode(str) {
  str = [...str];
  //    ^ es20XX spread to Array: keeps surrogate pairs
  let i = str.length, aRet = [];

  while (i--) {
      var iC = str[i].codePointAt(0);
      if (iC < 65 || iC > 127 || (iC>90 && iC<97)) {
          aRet[i] = '&#'+iC+';';
      } else {
          aRet[i] = str[i];
      }
  }
  return aRet.join('');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Another approach is using `Array.map`.

```js
const toHtmlEntities = (str, showInHtml = false) => 
  [...str].map( v => `${showInHtml ? `&amp;#` : `&#`}${
    v.codePointAt(0)};`).join(``);
const str = `&Hellõ Wórld `;
//                        ^ surrogate pair

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<ul>
  <li>Show the entities (<code>toHtmlEntities(str, true)</code>): <b>${
    toHtmlEntities(str, true)}</b></li>
  <li>Let the browser decide (<code>toHtmlEntities(str)</code>): <b>${
    toHtmlEntities(str)}</b></li>
  <li id="textOnly"></li></ul>`);
document.querySelector(`#textOnly`).textContent = `As textContent: ${
  toHtmlEntities(str)}`;
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px / 18px "normal verdana", arial;
  margin: 1rem;
}

code {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: This sounds really clever but I can only get it to convert the basics: `<>&`

Comment: nvm. It runs in a console fine, but when you output to the browser it looks like it hasn't converted stuff. What is up with that?

Comment: @Moss: the browser renders the htmlencoded characters to the characters they represent. The advantage of html-encoded characters is that a browser doesn't have to guess about the translation of (e.g.) diacritical characters and thus always renders those characters like they should be rendered.

Comment: You might consider changing this to remove the array-like access off of str. IE7 and below don't support that, and you can just as easily call charCodeAt right off of str with i as the argument. `var iC = str.charCodeAt(i)`

Comment: This code is not producing the correct HTML Entity value for the ± character which should be &#177; but it is returning &#65533; which is an unknown character �.

Comment: @Paul you should have specified the browser you used, I can't reproduce that (I get `&#177;`)

Comment: @YokovL: please leave the curly braces (try source of the answer @ https://www.jslint.com/)

Answer (score 27):

Create a function that uses string `replace`

```
function convert(str)
{
  str = str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
  str = str.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  str = str.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
  str = str.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
  str = str.replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
  return str;
}
```

Comment: I was facing issue with only single quotes( ') & double quotes (") in my input value to display in html. Script was breaking if user add it.

Answer (score 23):

From Mozilla ...

> Note that charCodeAt will always return a value that is less than 65,536. This is because the higher code points are represented by a pair of (lower valued) "surrogate" pseudo-characters which are used to comprise the real character. Because of this, in order to examine or reproduce the full character for individual characters of value 65,536 and above, for such characters, it is necessary to retrieve not only charCodeAt(i), but also charCodeAt(i+1) (as if examining/reproducing a string with two >letters).

The Best Solution

```
/**
 * (c) 2012 Steven Levithan <http://slevithan.com/>
 * MIT license
 */
if (!String.prototype.codePointAt) {
    String.prototype.codePointAt = function (pos) {
        pos = isNaN(pos) ? 0 : pos;
        var str = String(this),
            code = str.charCodeAt(pos),
            next = str.charCodeAt(pos + 1);
        // If a surrogate pair
        if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF && 0xDC00 <= next && next <= 0xDFFF) {
            return ((code - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (next - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
        }
        return code;
    };
}

/**
 * Encodes special html characters
 * @param string
 * @return {*}
 */
function html_encode(string) {
    var ret_val = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { 
        if (string.codePointAt(i) > 127) {
            ret_val += '&#' + string.codePointAt(i) + ';';
        } else {
            ret_val += string.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Usage example:

```
html_encode("✈");
```

Answer (score 12):

As was [mentioned by dragon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript#comment12409492_784698) the cleanest way to do it is with [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

```
function htmlEncode(s) {
    return $('<div>').text(s).html();
}

function htmlDecode(s) {
    return $('<div>').html(s).text();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but if your string contains a space, this won't alter it.  A better way is to use encodeURI(yourString);

Comment: A space is not a special character. `encodeURI` is for encoding URLs not HTML... it is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 9):

```
function char_convert() {

    var chars = ["©","Û","®","ž","Ü","Ÿ","Ý","$","Þ","%","¡","ß","¢","à","£","á","À","¤","â","Á","¥","ã","Â","¦","ä","Ã","§","å","Ä","¨","æ","Å","©","ç","Æ","ª","è","Ç","«","é","È","¬","ê","É","­","ë","Ê","®","ì","Ë","¯","í","Ì","°","î","Í","±","ï","Î","²","ð","Ï","³","ñ","Ð","´","ò","Ñ","µ","ó","Õ","¶","ô","Ö","·","õ","Ø","¸","ö","Ù","¹","÷","Ú","º","ø","Û","»","ù","Ü","@","¼","ú","Ý","½","û","Þ","€","¾","ü","ß","¿","ý","à","‚","À","þ","á","ƒ","Á","ÿ","å","„","Â","æ","…","Ã","ç","†","Ä","è","‡","Å","é","ˆ","Æ","ê","‰","Ç","ë","Š","È","ì","‹","É","í","Œ","Ê","î","Ë","ï","Ž","Ì","ð","Í","ñ","Î","ò","‘","Ï","ó","’","Ð","ô","“","Ñ","õ","”","Ò","ö","•","Ó","ø","–","Ô","ù","—","Õ","ú","˜","Ö","û","™","×","ý","š","Ø","þ","›","Ù","ÿ","œ","Ú"]; 
    var codes = ["&copy;","&#219;","&reg;","&#158;","&#220;","&#159;","&#221;","&#36;","&#222;","&#37;","&#161;","&#223;","&#162;","&#224;","&#163;","&#225;","&Agrave;","&#164;","&#226;","&Aacute;","&#165;","&#227;","&Acirc;","&#166;","&#228;","&Atilde;","&#167;","&#229;","&Auml;","&#168;","&#230;","&Aring;","&#169;","&#231;","&AElig;","&#170;","&#232;","&Ccedil;","&#171;","&#233;","&Egrave;","&#172;","&#234;","&Eacute;","&#173;","&#235;","&Ecirc;","&#174;","&#236;","&Euml;","&#175;","&#237;","&Igrave;","&#176;","&#238;","&Iacute;","&#177;","&#239;","&Icirc;","&#178;","&#240;","&Iuml;","&#179;","&#241;","&ETH;","&#180;","&#242;","&Ntilde;","&#181;","&#243;","&Otilde;","&#182;","&#244;","&Ouml;","&#183;","&#245;","&Oslash;","&#184;","&#246;","&Ugrave;","&#185;","&#247;","&Uacute;","&#186;","&#248;","&Ucirc;","&#187;","&#249;","&Uuml;","&#64;","&#188;","&#250;","&Yacute;","&#189;","&#251;","&THORN;","&#128;","&#190;","&#252","&szlig;","&#191;","&#253;","&agrave;","&#130;","&#192;","&#254;","&aacute;","&#131;","&#193;","&#255;","&aring;","&#132;","&#194;","&aelig;","&#133;","&#195;","&ccedil;","&#134;","&#196;","&egrave;","&#135;","&#197;","&eacute;","&#136;","&#198;","&ecirc;","&#137;","&#199;","&euml;","&#138;","&#200;","&igrave;","&#139;","&#201;","&iacute;","&#140;","&#202;","&icirc;","&#203;","&iuml;","&#142;","&#204;","&eth;","&#205;","&ntilde;","&#206;","&ograve;","&#145;","&#207;","&oacute;","&#146;","&#208;","&ocirc;","&#147;","&#209;","&otilde;","&#148;","&#210;","&ouml;","&#149;","&#211;","&oslash;","&#150;","&#212;","&ugrave;","&#151;","&#213;","&uacute;","&#152;","&#214;","&ucirc;","&#153;","&#215;","&yacute;","&#154;","&#216;","&thorn;","&#155;","&#217;","&yuml;","&#156;","&#218;"];

    for(x=0; x<chars.length; x++){
        for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            arguments[i].value = arguments[i].value.replace(chars[x], codes[x]);
        }
    }
 }

char_convert(this);
```

Comment: This works great., But for some reason when mixed in with some JQuery Functionality, it misfires. Sometimes does into convert some, or only a couple. But in general, works great. onBlur="char_convert(this);"

Comment: Uh, I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" in Chrome and "arguments[i].value is undefined" in Firebug.

Comment: putting all of those special characters into an array like that is completely pointless. see other answers.

Comment: Best solution for me, the only one that converts í to &iacute; for example.

Comment: How do you get those chars from your keyboard?  I know this is a silly question butt...in OS X for example

Answer (score 6):

```javascript
function ConvChar(str) {
    c = {'&lt;':'&amp;lt;', '&gt;':'&amp;gt;', '&':'&amp;amp;',
         '"':'&amp;quot;', "'":'&amp;#039;', '#':'&amp;#035;' };

    return str.replace(/[&lt;&amp;>'"#]/g, function(s) { return c[s]; });
}

alert(ConvChar('&lt;-"-&-"->-&lt;-\'-#-\'->'));
```

Result:

```
&lt;-&quot;-&amp;-&quot;-&gt;-&lt;-&#039;-&#035;-&#039;-&gt;
```

In a testarea tag:

```
<-"-&-"->-<-'-#-'->
```

If you'll just change a few characters in long code...

Answer (score 6):

If you need support for [**all standardized named character references**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#named-character-references), [**Unicode**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) and [**ambiguous ampersands**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands), the [***he***](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library is the only 100% reliable solution I'm aware of!

---

#### Example use

```
he.encode('foo © bar ≠ baz  qux');
// Output: 'foo &#xA9; bar &#x2260; baz &#x1D306; qux'

he.decode('foo &copy; bar &ne; baz &#x1D306; qux');
// Output: 'foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'
```

Answer (score 4):

In a `PRE` tag - and in most other HTML tags - plain text for a batch file that uses the output redirection characters (`<` and `>`) will break the HTML, but **here is my tip**: anything goes in a `TEXTAREA` element - it will not break the HTML, mainly because we are inside a control instanced and handled by the OS, and therefore its content are not being parsed by the HTML engine.

As an example, say I want to highlight the syntax of my batch file using JavaScript. I simply paste the code in a textarea without worrying about the HTML reserved characters, and have the script process the `innerHTML` property of the textarea, which evaluates to the text with the HTML reserved characters replaced by their corresponding [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) entities.

Browsers will escape special characters automatically when you retrieve the `innerHTML` (and `outerHTML`) property of an element. Using a textarea (and who knows, maybe an input of type text) just saves you from doing the conversion (manually or through code).

I use this trick to test my syntax highlighter, and when I'm done authoring and testing, I simply hide the textarea from view.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround:

```
var temp = $("div").text("<");
var afterEscape = temp.html(); // afterEscape == "&lt;"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>html</title>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "&amp;";
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can simply convert special characters to HTML using the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var swapCodes   = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230, 8482, 169, 61558, 8226, 61607);
var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'",  "'",  '"',  '"',  "*",  "...", "&trade;", "&copy;", "&bull;", "&bull;", "&bull;");

var TextCheck = {
    doCWBind:function(div){
        $(div).bind({
            bind:function(){
                TextCheck.cleanWord(div);
            },
            focus:function(){
                TextCheck.cleanWord(div);
            },
            paste:function(){
                TextCheck.cleanWord(div);
            }
        });
    },
    cleanWord:function(div){
        var output = $(div).val();
        for (i = 0; i < swapCodes.length; i++) {
            var swapper = new RegExp("\\u" + swapCodes[i].toString(16), "g");
            output = output.replace(swapper, swapStrings[i]);
        }
        $(div).val(output);
    }
}
```

Another one that we use now that works. The one above I have it calling a script instead and returns the converted code. It is only good on small textareas (meaning not a full on article, blog, etc.)

---

For the above. It works on most characters.

```
var swapCodes   = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230, 8482, 61558, 8226, 61607, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 338, 339, 352, 353, 376, 402);
var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'",  "'",  '"',  '"',  "*",  "...", "&trade;", "&bull;", "&bull;", "&bull;", "&iexcl;", "&cent;", "&pound;", "&curren;", "&yen;", "&brvbar;", "&sect;", "&uml;", "&copy;", "&ordf;", "&laquo;", "&not;", "&shy;", "&reg;", "&macr;", "&deg;", "&plusmn;", "&sup2;", "&sup3;", "&acute;", "&micro;", "&para;", "&middot;", "&cedil;", "&sup1;", "&ordm;", "&raquo;", "&frac14;", "&frac12;", "&frac34;", "&iquest;", "&Agrave;", "&Aacute;", "&Acirc;", "&Atilde;", "&Auml;", "&Aring;", "&AElig;", "&Ccedil;", "&Egrave;", "&Eacute;", "&Ecirc;", "&Euml;", "&Igrave;", "&Iacute;", "&Icirc;", "&Iuml;", "&ETH;", "&Ntilde;", "&Ograve;", "&Oacute;", "&Ocirc;", "&Otilde;", "&Ouml;", "&times;", "&Oslash;", "&Ugrave;", "&Uacute;", "&Ucirc;", "&Uuml;", "&Yacute;", "&THORN;", "&szlig;", "&agrave;", "&aacute;", "&acirc;", "&atilde;", "&auml;", "&aring;", "&aelig;", "&ccedil;", "&egrave;", "&eacute;", "&ecirc;", "&euml;", "&igrave;", "&iacute;", "&icirc;", "&iuml;", "&eth;", "&ntilde;", "&ograve;", "&oacute;", "&ocirc;", "&otilde;", "&ouml;", "&divide;", "&oslash;", "&ugrave;", "&uacute;", "&ucirc;", "&uuml;", "&yacute;", "&thorn;", "&yuml;", "&#338;", "&#339;", "&#352;", "&#353;", "&#376;", "&#402;");
```

---

I create a javascript file that has a lot of functionality including the above.
http://www.neotropicsolutions.com/JSChars.zip

All files needed are included. I added jQuery 1.4.4. Simply because I saw issues in other versions, yet to try them out.

```
Requires: jQuery & jQuery Impromptu from: http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php

1. Word Count
2. Character Conversion
3. Checks to ensure this is not passed: "notsomeverylongstringmissingspaces"
4. Checks to make sure ALL IS NOT ALL UPPERCASE.
5. Strip HTML

    // Word Counter
    $.getScript('js/characters.js', function(){
        $('#adtxt').bind("keyup click blur focus change paste",
            function(event){
                TextCheck.wordCount(30, "#adtxt", "#adtxt_count", event);
        });
        $('#adtxt').blur(
            function(event){
                TextCheck.check_length('#adtxt'); // unsures properly spaces-not one long word
                TextCheck.doCWBind('#adtxt'); // char conversion
        });

        TextCheck.wordCount(30, "#adtxt", "#adtxt_count", false);
    });

    //HTML
    <textarea name="adtxt" id="adtxt" rows="10" cols="70" class="wordCount"></textarea>

    <div id="adtxt_count" class="clear"></div>

    // Just Character Conversions:
    TextCheck.doCWBind('#myfield');

    // Run through form fields in a form for case checking.
    // Alerts user when field is blur'd.
    var labels = new Array("Brief Description", "Website URL", "Contact Name", "Website", "Email", "Linkback URL");
    var checking = new Array("descr", "title", "fname", "website", "email", "linkback");
    TextCheck.check_it(checking, labels);

    // Extra security to check again, make sure form is not submitted
    var pass = TextCheck.validate(checking, labels);
    if(pass){
        // Do form actions
    }

    //Strip HTML
    <textarea name="adtxt" id="adtxt" rows="10" cols="70" onblur="TextCheck.stripHTML(this);"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good library I've found very useful in this context.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

According to its author:

> It supports all standardized named character references as per HTML,
>   handles ambiguous ampersands and other edge cases just like a browser
>   would, has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other
>   JavaScript solutions — he handles astral Unicode symbols just fine

Comment: This tool https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he for mathias is very good and have online playground also

Answer (score 1):

```
function escape (text)
{
  return text.replace(/[<>\&\"\']/g, function(c) {
    return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
  });
}

alert(escape("<>&'\""));
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't direcly answer your question, but if you are using `innerHTML` in order to write text within an element and you ran into encoding issues, just use `textContent`, i.e.:

```
var s = "Foo 'bar' baz <qux>";

var element = document.getElementById('foo');
element.textContent = s;

// <div id="foo">Foo 'bar' baz <qux></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple methods I use without the need of [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

You can **encode every character** in your string:

```
function encode(e){return e.replace(/[^]/g, function(e) {return "&#" + e.charCodeAt(0) + ";"})}
```

Or just target the main **safe encoding characters** to worry about (&, inebreaks, <, >, " and ') like:

```js
function encode(r){
    return r.replace(/[\x26\x0A\<>'"]/g, function(r){return "&#" + r.charCodeAt(0) + ";"})
}

test.value = encode('How to encode\nonly html tags &<>\'" nice & fast!');

/*************
* \x26 is &ampersand (it has to be first),
* \x0A is newline,
*************/
```

```html
<textarea id=test rows="9" cols="55">www.WHAK.com</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use JavaScript's `DOMParser` for special characters conversion.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const convertedValue = (parser.parseFromString("&#039 &amp &#039 &lt &gt", "application/xml").body.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can do (copy pasted from documentation):

```
_.escape('fred, barney, & pebbles');
// => 'fred, barney, &amp; pebbles'
```

For more information: *[_.escape([string=''])](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#escape)*

Answer (score 0):

I had struggled with this myself for quite some time, but I settled on using this negative match regex to match all special characters and convert them to their relevant character codes:

```
var encoded = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(i) {
    return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var str = "&\"'<>";
            alert('B4 Change: \n' + str);

            str = str.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;');
            str = str.replace(/</g,  '&lt;');
            str = str.replace(/>/g,  '&gt;');
            str = str.replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');
            str = str.replace(/\'/g, '&#039;');

            alert('After change: \n' + str);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Use this to test: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_text

Comment: The link is broken: *"The file you asked for does not exist "*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but if you need to insert the resulting string somewhere without it being converted back, you need to do:

```
str.replace(/'/g,"&amp;amp;#39;"); // and so on
```

Comment: "Yes" in response to some other answer?

Comment: I guess so - it was soooo long ago.

Answer (score -1):

The following is the a function to encode XML escaped characters in JavaScript:

```
Encoder.htmlEncode(unsafeText);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function HTMLCharConvert(text: string) {
    var swapCodes = new Array(8211, 8212, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8230, 8482, 61558, 8226, 61607, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 338, 339, 352, 353, 376, 402);
    var swapStrings = new Array("--", "--", "'", "'", '"', '"', "*", "...", "&trade;", "&bull;", "&bull;", "&bull;", "&iexcl;", "&cent;", "&pound;", "&curren;", "&yen;", "&brvbar;", "&sect;", "&uml;", "&copy;", "&ordf;", "&laquo;", "&not;", "&shy;", "&reg;", "&macr;", "&deg;", "&plusmn;", "&sup2;", "&sup3;", "&acute;", "&micro;", "&para;", "&middot;", "&cedil;", "&sup1;", "&ordm;", "&raquo;", "&frac14;", "&frac12;", "&frac34;", "&iquest;", "&Agrave;", "&Aacute;", "&Acirc;", "&Atilde;", "&Auml;", "&Aring;", "&AElig;", "&Ccedil;", "&Egrave;", "&Eacute;", "&Ecirc;", "&Euml;", "&Igrave;", "&Iacute;", "&Icirc;", "&Iuml;", "&ETH;", "&Ntilde;", "&Ograve;", "&Oacute;", "&Ocirc;", "&Otilde;", "&Ouml;", "&times;", "&Oslash;", "&Ugrave;", "&Uacute;", "&Ucirc;", "&Uuml;", "&Yacute;", "&THORN;", "&szlig;", "&agrave;", "&aacute;", "&acirc;", "&atilde;", "&auml;", "&aring;", "&aelig;", "&ccedil;", "&egrave;", "&eacute;", "&ecirc;", "&euml;", "&igrave;", "&iacute;", "&icirc;", "&iuml;", "&eth;", "&ntilde;", "&ograve;", "&oacute;", "&ocirc;", "&otilde;", "&ouml;", "&divide;", "&oslash;", "&ugrave;", "&uacute;", "&ucirc;", "&uuml;", "&yacute;", "&thorn;", "&yuml;", "&#338;", "&#339;", "&#352;", "&#353;", "&#376;", "&#402;");

    for (let i = 0 ; i < swapCodes.length; i++) {
        const rep = '&#' + swapCodes[i] + ';'
        const idx = text.indexOf(rep)

        if (idx < 0)
            continue

        text = text.replaceAll(rep, swapStrings[i])
    }

    return text
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Use the JavaScript function [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions), that lets you encode strings.

**E.g.,**

```
escape("yourString");
```

Comment: Encode for putting in a URL not for HTML (and the function is deprecated anyway since it is broken for Unicode).