# HTML Entity Decode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I encode and decode HTML entities using JavaScript or JQuery?

```
var varTitle = "Chris&apos; corner";
```

I want it to be:

```
var varTitle = "Chris' corner";
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it?lq=1). Seems better than what is offered below.

Comment: Also see the ent module (on npm!) https://github.com/substack/node-ent

Comment: I think @ringø (wow, oddly similar username...) meant to link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394787/114558)

Comment: @rinogo I thought [this was the better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915311/441930). apparently the [he](https://www.npmjs.com/package/he) lib is designed for exactly this purpose. You might be able to save a few lines of code with a custom implementation like most of the answers here, but they all have limitations one way or another.

Comment: A more concise way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64587244/9854149

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You could try something like:

```js
var Title = $('<textarea />').html("Chris&apos; corner").text();
console.log(Title);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC8Ty/204/).

A more interactive version:

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  var theString = $('#string').val();
  var varTitle = $('<textarea />').html(theString).text();
  $('#output').text(varTitle);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="string">Enter a html-encoded string to decode</label>
    <input type="text" name="string" id="string" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="decode" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC8Ty/205/).

Comment: Cool that works.  So just curious, the $('div />') is used to create a <div> element around the varTitle?

Comment: @chris and @david - This code creates an empty (detached from DOM) div and sets it's innerHTML and finally retrieved back as normal text. It's not *surrounding it with a DIV*, but *putting it in a div*. I putting some emphasis over this since it's crucial to understand how jQuery works.

Comment: Do NOT use this with untrusted data, see Mike's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery#comment6018122_2419664

Comment: its good but doesn't allways work it works within a div tag but for example if you type in some php or css without the html it lets it through

Comment: just chiming in. this is vulnerable to xss attacks, try them! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282274/exploiting-jquery-html-encoding-xss

Comment: How we can use this for Titanium Appcelerator?

Comment: `$('<textarea />').html("Chris&apos; corner").text();` will this attach a `textarea` to document?

Comment: it is jQuery only...

Comment: I'ts cool. But, please - compare execute results `jQuery('<textarea />').html('<span>hi</span>').text()` and `jQuery('<textarea />').html('<span>hi</span><script>wow</script>').text()` : it is underwater stones

Comment: This can be vulnerable to XSS attacks for older jQuery versions ([see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395954/6476044)). I would suggest using [he library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) instead. You can see code examples in another [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596964/6476044).

Answer (score 315):

I recommend against using the jQuery code that was accepted as the answer. While it does not insert the string to decode into the page, it does cause things such as scripts and HTML elements to get created. This is way more code than we need. Instead, I suggest using a safer, more optimized function.

```
var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LYteC/4/

To use this function, just call `decodeEntities("&amp;")` and it will use the same underlying techniques as the jQuery version will—but without jQuery's overhead, and after sanitizing the HTML tags in the input. See [Mike Samuel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery#comment6018122_2419664) on the accepted answer for how to filter out HTML tags.

This function can be easily used as a jQuery plugin by adding the following line in your project.

```
jQuery.decodeEntities = decodeEntities;
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what  str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
does?

Comment: @PoeHaH It strips out all html tags, both opening and closing.

Comment: Note: textContent is not supported in IE8, so if that's still one of your targeted browsers, you have to find another solution. I just wasted an hour trying to figure that out, since we need to decode entities specifically to compensate for another IE8 bug.

Comment: @GregCharles I don't know of any good alternatives for IE8 and lower. There's no particularly convenient way to get the text content of a node without textContent.

Comment: @RobertK -- I was able to do it with:   jQuery('<div />').html(str).text();, so the jQuery folks figured out a way. I have jQuery on the page anyway, but if it really needed to be done without it, you could step into the code and see how they did it.

Comment: @GregCharles -- Using the `jQuery('<div />').html(str).text();` method is not safe. You can include JavaScript in the string which will be run. That's why this function strips out HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Doesn't IE allow for `innerText` in lieu of `textContent` though?

Comment: According to Quirksmode, IE does allow for `innerText`. I'll play around with it a little later and verify that before I update my answer.

Comment: Careful with the line that takes out HTML tags. You shouldn't be using regex with HTML/XML. Bobince has made this clear for ages.

Comment: @EruPenkman I don't understand why you posted that. What's your point?

Comment: is there a reason why you chose to create a block element (div) instead of an inline one? ... Asking as someone who successfully wanted HTML entities in a Javascript-driven placeholder and used a <span> instead of a div to avoid any height:auto related issues...

Comment: @vzR Returning node.textContent is similar to node.innerText, and won't contain the node's tag. Therefore, changing the element you write to has no effect on the returned result.

Comment: While this is nice, users should be aware that it is pretty dangerous. It may appear that it properly strips "dangerous stuff" out, but it can be easily defeated. Do not use this on untrusted user input unless you like getting xss attacked.

Comment: @Qix I don't completely understand the problem here.  HTML/XML should certainly not be "parsed with regexes" as people so often do.  If all you're trying to do is tokenize it, then AFAIK regexes are exactly an ideal solution.  Unless I'm missing something, stripping the tags completely shouldn't require anything beyond lexical analysis and thus there'd be no benefit to going beyond regexes here.

Comment: I greatly simplified this code, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55142351/5286034).

Comment: can someone tell me why this code doesn't work nicely with ```&#039;```? It always returns ```\'```, putting a random slash infront. I tried ```&#034;``` and the code returned ```"``` jsut fine. Here's the string I'm using:
```&quot;Silhouette&quot;, a song performed by the group &#039;KANA-BOON&#039; is featured as the sixteenth opening of which anime?```

Comment: **CAUTION** : The regular expression method to remove `<script>` tags isn't safe. Typically, `< script>alert('xss')</script>` will pass just because of the space after the opening `<` char. At a minimum, I would use `/<\s*script[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*script\s*>/gis` to be a bit safer. But I wouldn't be surprised if someone manages to trick it. @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED is totally right, it's dangerous to try and solve this with a regular expression. Same problem with your second regex: `< img onload="alert('xss')" href="/wrong-url" />` passes without any problem :-(

Comment: This answer should be edited to mention the security risks it has. As [mentioned clearly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery/1395954#1395954), we should never create a `<div>` element to solve the problem as it will execute some JS. It's not the case if we create a `<textarea>` element.

Answer (score 134):

***Edit 2023: These days you should use a library like [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he).***

Like Robert K said, don't use jQuery.html().text() to decode html entities as it's unsafe because user input should never have access to the DOM. Read about [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) for why this is unsafe.

Instead try the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) utility-belt library which comes with [escape](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) and [unescape](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) methods:

[**_.escape(string)**](http://underscorejs.org/#escape)

Escapes a string for insertion into HTML, replacing `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `` ` ``, and `'` characters.

```
_.escape('Curly, Larry & Moe');
=> "Curly, Larry &amp; Moe"
```

[**_.unescape(string)**](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape)

The opposite of escape, replaces `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&#96;` and `&#x27;` with their unescaped counterparts.

```
_.unescape('Curly, Larry &amp; Moe');
=> "Curly, Larry & Moe"
```

To support decoding more characters, just copy the Underscore [unescape](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-137) method and add more characters to the map.

Comment: TypeError: _.unescape is not a function

Comment: @chovy, use the latest Underscore.js version >= 1.4.2 and you won't get a TypeError.

Comment: This is basically the only that works for me. I need to find script tags containing templates, and then search through those to find subsections of those templates. When doing this with jQuery, jQ converts all "invalid" html (aka the template tags) to entities. In order to retrieve the subsections, they need to be unescaped again, and for that, none of the other answers work.

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't require a DOM, and nowadays who can guarantee access to the DOM API when writing javascript?  Unfortunately it only works for the listed entities, and leaves things like &nbsp; untouched.

Comment: I like the spirit of this answer. Find a library that does it, use it, or go their source, and copy the logic.

Comment: +1 for using a source-controlled library rather than copying and pasting some random code from the top stack overflow answer. If only the javascript standard library had these kind of low-level functions.

Comment: Keep in mind that it does not unencode encoded russian or japanese characters. e.g. &#x30cf;&#x30ed;&#x30fc;&#x30ef;&#x30fc;&#x30eb;&#x30c9; ->  ハローワールド cannot be done with this

Comment: `_.unescape` only works for [a handful of values](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-160). So something like `_.unescape('&raquo;')` for example will just return `"&raquo;"`

Comment: this doesn't work with lodash

Answer (score 115):

[Original author answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787#7394787).

This is my favourite way of decoding HTML characters. The advantage of using this code is that tags are also preserved.

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k65s3/

Input:

```
Entity:&nbsp;Bad attempt at XSS:<script>alert('new\nline?')</script><br>
```

Output:

```
Entity: Bad attempt at XSS:<script>alert('new\nline?')</script><br>
```

Comment: This method works every where even when jquery is not available or not loaded yet, because its pure javascript.

Comment: Is there any drawback to this technique? It seems way easier than the answers above.

Comment: @anthonygood I don't think so.

Comment: @anthonygood each time the function creates a new object (DOM element)

Comment: You could wrap this in an immediately-invoked function expression so that the DOM element is only created once:

`const decodeHTMLEntities = (() => {
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

  return (message: string): string => {
    textArea.innerHTML = message;
    return textArea.value;
  };
})();`

Comment: Next time @insign please credit the original author or give a link to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394787

Comment: @geauser yes, done

Comment: This is the best and most useful answer in the whole list. Thanks @insign.

Comment: This is the reason people hate JS :-D

Comment: This is the best answer, whoever browses the thread, try this!

Answer (score 60):

Here's a quick method that doesn't require creating a div, and decodes the "most common" HTML escaped chars:

```js
function decodeHTMLEntities(text) {
    var entities = [
        ['amp', '&'],
        ['apos', '\''],
        ['#x27', '\''],
        ['#x2F', '/'],
        ['#39', '\''],
        ['#47', '/'],
        ['lt', '<'],
        ['gt', '>'],
        ['nbsp', ' '],
        ['quot', '"']
    ];

    for (var i = 0, max = entities.length; i < max; ++i)
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('&' + entities[i][0] + ';', 'g'), entities[i][1]);

    return text;
}

console.log(decodeHTMLEntities('&amp; &quot;'));
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work at all for most html entities, and expanding it to include them would be pretty repetitive and error-prone. E.g., there's an entity for each Japanese kanji character, of which there are thousands. Plus by that point, I wouldn't be surprised if your answer was slower than some of the others here, since you'd be running thousands of replaces with thousands of regexes for each string to decode.

Comment: It really depends on your PURPOSE when you are encoding these strings. If your goal is to have it not trigger HTML processing via things like < or > it is entirely unnecessary to encode the other characters via the character entity syntax. The extensive amount of character entities serve mostly as a convenience tool. The entities I have listed are the bare minimum of ones you must escape to avoid having the data get mixed up with HTML. 
[Continued in next comment]

Comment: As for the speed thing, good point on having run multiple regexes. But of course since your idea of putting every character entity into that code is pointless and frankly, really stupid, this is not an issue. One could however generate the regex using the | character first and do a single replace() call. I think you'd have to benchmark it to see which is faster, but my gut says it'll be faster to use | with one replace() due to function call overhead being high in Javascript.

Comment: Right, so your solution is incomplete. The OP never said why they were encoding their HTML entities so if you were making an assumption on that front, it probably should have been noted in the answer.

Comment: This is complete when you're trying to replicate htmlspecialchars_decode in javascript. It does not pretend to replicate html_entity_decode. I find there's alot of noise on this topic and many bloated/insecure methods.

This is the decode companion to the excellent encode solutions provided by Kip and Chris Jacob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: I was working with decoding reddit comments for a Vue.js app v-html directive, and it worked great. Thank you!

Comment: You should also replace ↵ with blank spaces.

Comment: for my google app script. I've use this because neither `Document` nor the any DOM manipulation is not available in google app scripts. thanks

Answer (score 37):

here is another version:

```js
function convertHTMLEntity(text){
    const span = document.createElement('span');

    return text
    .replace(/&[#A-Za-z0-9]+;/gi, (entity,position,text)=> {
        span.innerHTML = entity;
        return span.innerText;
    });
}

console.log(convertHTMLEntity('Large &lt; &#163; 500'));
```

Comment: Since you are matching both `A-Z` and `a-z`, is the case insensitive option needed ?

Comment: @tigrou No, You can remove that option.

Comment: this is the best version thanks !

Comment: This is the best answer. I will upvote it.

Comment: Excellent solution, but still not sure how its working. Please explain your code.

Answer (score 22):

Inspired by Robert K's solution, this version does not strip HTML tags, and is just as secure.

```
var decode_entities = (function() {
    // Remove HTML Entities
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    function decode_HTML_entities (str) {

        if(str && typeof str === 'string') {

            // Escape HTML before decoding for HTML Entities
            str = escape(str).replace(/%26/g,'&').replace(/%23/g,'#').replace(/%3B/g,';');

            element.innerHTML = str;
            if(element.innerText){
                str = element.innerText;
                element.innerText = '';
            }else{
                // Firefox support
                str = element.textContent;
                element.textContent = '';
            }
        }
        return unescape(str);
    }
    return decode_HTML_entities;
})();
```

Comment: Those `escape()` and `unescape()` functions are deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Answer (score 17):

jQuery provides a way to encode and decode html entities.

If you use a "<div/>" tag, it will strip out all the html.

```
function htmlDecode(value) {
    return $("<div/>").html(value).text();
}

function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

If you use a "<textarea/>" tag, it will preserve the html tags.

```
function htmlDecode(value) {
    return $("<textarea/>").html(value).text();
}

function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $('<textarea/>').text(value).html();
}
```

Comment: Love it, works for me, tested it in the Chrome console and indeed the <script> tags and any attributes it had are removed completely.

Comment: I also prefer this solution.  A pure JavaScript way to do it is creating a div with `var div = document.createElement('div');` and then setting `innerHTML` and getting `innerText` to unescape; vice-versa for escaping.

Comment: jQuery `text()` will strip html if it's invalid, like for ex. when using table rows.

Answer (score 13):

To add yet another "inspired by Robert K" to the list, here is another *safe* version which *does not strip HTML tags*. Instead of running the whole string through the HTML parser, it pulls out only the entities and converts those.

```
var decodeEntities = (function() {
    // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    // regular expression matching HTML entities
    var entity = /&(?:#x[a-f0-9]+|#[0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+);?/ig;

    return function decodeHTMLEntities(str) {
        // find and replace all the html entities
        str = str.replace(entity, function(m) {
            element.innerHTML = m;
            return element.textContent;
        });

        // reset the value
        element.textContent = '';

        return str;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by Robert K's solution, strips html tags and **prevents executing scripts** and eventhandlers like: `<img src=fake onerror="prompt(1)">`
Tested on latest Chrome, FF, IE (should work from IE9, but haven't tested).

```
var decodeEntities = (function () {
        //create a new html document (doesn't execute script tags in child elements)
        var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
        var element = doc.createElement('div');

        function getText(str) {
            element.innerHTML = str;
            str = element.textContent;
            element.textContent = '';
            return str;
        }

        function decodeHTMLEntities(str) {
            if (str && typeof str === 'string') {
                var x = getText(str);
                while (str !== x) {
                    str = x;
                    x = getText(x);
                }
                return x;
            }
        }
        return decodeHTMLEntities;
    })();
```

Simply call:

```
decodeEntities('<img src=fake onerror="prompt(1)">');
decodeEntities("<script>alert('aaa!')</script>");
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a full version

```
function htmldecode(s){
    window.HTML_ESC_MAP = {
    "nbsp":" ","iexcl":"¡","cent":"¢","pound":"£","curren":"¤","yen":"¥","brvbar":"¦","sect":"§","uml":"¨","copy":"©","ordf":"ª","laquo":"«","not":"¬","reg":"®","macr":"¯","deg":"°","plusmn":"±","sup2":"²","sup3":"³","acute":"´","micro":"µ","para":"¶","middot":"·","cedil":"¸","sup1":"¹","ordm":"º","raquo":"»","frac14":"¼","frac12":"½","frac34":"¾","iquest":"¿","Agrave":"À","Aacute":"Á","Acirc":"Â","Atilde":"Ã","Auml":"Ä","Aring":"Å","AElig":"Æ","Ccedil":"Ç","Egrave":"È","Eacute":"É","Ecirc":"Ê","Euml":"Ë","Igrave":"Ì","Iacute":"Í","Icirc":"Î","Iuml":"Ï","ETH":"Ð","Ntilde":"Ñ","Ograve":"Ò","Oacute":"Ó","Ocirc":"Ô","Otilde":"Õ","Ouml":"Ö","times":"×","Oslash":"Ø","Ugrave":"Ù","Uacute":"Ú","Ucirc":"Û","Uuml":"Ü","Yacute":"Ý","THORN":"Þ","szlig":"ß","agrave":"à","aacute":"á","acirc":"â","atilde":"ã","auml":"ä","aring":"å","aelig":"æ","ccedil":"ç","egrave":"è","eacute":"é","ecirc":"ê","euml":"ë","igrave":"ì","iacute":"í","icirc":"î","iuml":"ï","eth":"ð","ntilde":"ñ","ograve":"ò","oacute":"ó","ocirc":"ô","otilde":"õ","ouml":"ö","divide":"÷","oslash":"ø","ugrave":"ù","uacute":"ú","ucirc":"û","uuml":"ü","yacute":"ý","thorn":"þ","yuml":"ÿ","fnof":"ƒ","Alpha":"Α","Beta":"Β","Gamma":"Γ","Delta":"Δ","Epsilon":"Ε","Zeta":"Ζ","Eta":"Η","Theta":"Θ","Iota":"Ι","Kappa":"Κ","Lambda":"Λ","Mu":"Μ","Nu":"Ν","Xi":"Ξ","Omicron":"Ο","Pi":"Π","Rho":"Ρ","Sigma":"Σ","Tau":"Τ","Upsilon":"Υ","Phi":"Φ","Chi":"Χ","Psi":"Ψ","Omega":"Ω","alpha":"α","beta":"β","gamma":"γ","delta":"δ","epsilon":"ε","zeta":"ζ","eta":"η","theta":"θ","iota":"ι","kappa":"κ","lambda":"λ","mu":"μ","nu":"ν","xi":"ξ","omicron":"ο","pi":"π","rho":"ρ","sigmaf":"ς","sigma":"σ","tau":"τ","upsilon":"υ","phi":"φ","chi":"χ","psi":"ψ","omega":"ω","thetasym":"ϑ","upsih":"ϒ","piv":"ϖ","bull":"•","hellip":"…","prime":"′","Prime":"″","oline":"‾","frasl":"⁄","weierp":"℘","image":"ℑ","real":"ℜ","trade":"™","alefsym":"ℵ","larr":"←","uarr":"↑","rarr":"→","darr":"↓","harr":"↔","crarr":"↵","lArr":"⇐","uArr":"⇑","rArr":"⇒","dArr":"⇓","hArr":"⇔","forall":"∀","part":"∂","exist":"∃","empty":"∅","nabla":"∇","isin":"∈","notin":"∉","ni":"∋","prod":"∏","sum":"∑","minus":"−","lowast":"∗","radic":"√","prop":"∝","infin":"∞","ang":"∠","and":"∧","or":"∨","cap":"∩","cup":"∪","int":"∫","there4":"∴","sim":"∼","cong":"≅","asymp":"≈","ne":"≠","equiv":"≡","le":"≤","ge":"≥","sub":"⊂","sup":"⊃","nsub":"⊄","sube":"⊆","supe":"⊇","oplus":"⊕","otimes":"⊗","perp":"⊥","sdot":"⋅","lceil":"⌈","rceil":"⌉","lfloor":"⌊","rfloor":"⌋","lang":"〈","rang":"〉","loz":"◊","spades":"♠","clubs":"♣","hearts":"♥","diams":"♦","\"":"quot","amp":"&","lt":"<","gt":">","OElig":"Œ","oelig":"œ","Scaron":"Š","scaron":"š","Yuml":"Ÿ","circ":"ˆ","tilde":"˜","ndash":"–","mdash":"—","lsquo":"‘","rsquo":"’","sbquo":"‚","ldquo":"“","rdquo":"”","bdquo":"„","dagger":"†","Dagger":"‡","permil":"‰","lsaquo":"‹","rsaquo":"›","euro":"€"};
    if(!window.HTML_ESC_MAP_EXP)
        window.HTML_ESC_MAP_EXP = new RegExp("&("+Object.keys(HTML_ESC_MAP).join("|")+");","g");
    return s?s.replace(window.HTML_ESC_MAP_EXP,function(x){
        return HTML_ESC_MAP[x.substring(1,x.length-1)]||x;
    }):s;
}
```

Usage

```
htmldecode("&sum;&nbsp;&gt;&euro;");
```

Comment: be careful with nbsp char, I had to manually replace it because this example use a normal space.

Comment: How about for characters like `&#232;`?

Answer (score 11):

A more functional approach to @William Lahti's answer:

```js
var entities = {
    'amp': '&',
    'apos': '\'',
    '#x27': '\'',
    '#x2F': '/',
    '#39': '\'',
    '#47': '/',
    'lt': '<',
    'gt': '>',
    'nbsp': ' ',
    'quot': '"'
};

function decodeHTMLEntities(text) {
    return text.replace(/&([^;]+);/gm, function (match, entity) {
        return entities[entity] || match
    })
}

console.log(decodeHTMLEntities('Large &lt; &#163; 500'));
```

Comment: this doesn't address the problem of the decodeHTMLEntities('&#228;') or ä :)

Comment: The list is surely not complete, it is just a rewrite of the accepted answer. You can add whatever you want to the entities list, just add '#228': 'ä'.

Comment: I think doing that for the ****** thousand special characters tath could be there could mean the death :(

Comment: If you need to support all chars, you are absolutely right. As I said, this is a rewrite of the accepted answer.

Comment: And incidentally, this is exactly what people like me need. I required a short list I could manage to put in a gatsby utility where document is unavailable. Wholly bulletproof isn't always the goal.

Answer (score 9):

Injecting untrusted HTML into the page is dangerous as explained in [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/jquery-decode-html-entities#comments-2419664).

One alternative is to use a JavaScript-only implementation of PHP's html_entity_decode (from http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424). The example would then be something like:

```
var varTitle = html_entity_decode("Chris&apos; corner");
```

Comment: Actually, the current version of html_entity_decode doesn't handle &apos;.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late to the game, but I thought I might provide the following snippet as an example of how I decode HTML entities using jQuery:

```
var varTitleE = "Chris&apos; corner";
var varTitleD = $("<div/>").html(varTitleE).text();

console.log(varTitleE + " vs. " + varTitleD);​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Don't forget to fire-up your inspector/firebug to see the console results -- or simply replace console.log(...) w/alert(...)

That said, here's what my console via the Google Chrome inspector read:

```
Chris&apos; corner vs. Chris' corner
```

Answer (score 2):

Because @Robert K and @mattcasey both have good code, I thought I'd contribute here with a CoffeeScript version, in case anyone in the future could use it:

```
    String::unescape = (strict = false) ->
      ###
      # Take escaped text, and return the unescaped version
      #
      # @param string str | String to be used
      # @param bool strict | Stict mode will remove all HTML
      #
      # Test it here:
      # https://jsfiddle.net/tigerhawkvok/t9pn1dn5/
      #
      # Code: https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/285b8631ed6ebef4446d
      ###
      # Create a dummy element
      element = document.createElement("div")
      decodeHTMLEntities = (str) ->
        if str? and typeof str is "string"
          unless strict is true
            # escape HTML tags
            str = escape(str).replace(/%26/g,'&').replace(/%23/g,'#').replace(/%3B/g,';')
          else
            str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '')
            str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '')
          element.innerHTML = str
          if element.innerText
            # Do we support innerText?
            str = element.innerText
            element.innerText = ""
          else
            # Firefox
            str = element.textContent
            element.textContent = ""
        unescape(str)
      # Remove encoded or double-encoded tags
      fixHtmlEncodings = (string) ->
        string = string.replace(/\&amp;#/mg, '&#') # The rest, for double-encodings
        string = string.replace(/\&quot;/mg, '"')
        string = string.replace(/\&quote;/mg, '"')
        string = string.replace(/\&#95;/mg, '_')
        string = string.replace(/\&#39;/mg, "'")
        string = string.replace(/\&#34;/mg, '"')
        string = string.replace(/\&#62;/mg, '>')
        string = string.replace(/\&#60;/mg, '<')
        string
      # Run it
      tmp = fixHtmlEncodings(this)
      decodeHTMLEntities(tmp)
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/tigerhawkvok/t9pn1dn5/7/ or https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/285b8631ed6ebef4446d (includes compiled JS, and is probably updated compared to this answer)

Answer (score 0):

To do it in pure javascript without jquery or predefining everything you can cycle the encoded html string through an elements innerHTML and innerText(/textContent) properties for every decode step that is required:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>For every decode step, cycle through innerHTML and innerText </title>
    <script>
function decode(str) {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.innerHTML = str; 
  return typeof d.innerText !== 'undefined' ? d.innerText : d.textContent;
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
var encodedString = "&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=\"font-size:xx-small;\"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";
    </script>
    <input type=button onclick="document.body.innerHTML=decode(encodedString)"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that is the exact opposite of the solution chosen.

```
var decoded = $("<div/>").text(encodedStr).html();
```

Try it :)

Comment: This method is not safe. You can include JavaScript in `encodedStr` which will be run. Use Robert K's method.