# How to decode HTML entity with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache, handlebars.js

I'm using the Handlebars templating engine on the app I'm building to render the data I get from the server.

I know that it escapes HTML values by default and that you have to use the triple brackets `{{{text}}}` in order for `text: <p>Example</p>` to be rendered as an HTML element.

The problem is, what do I do if the data I receive, including the HTML tags, is already escaped?

So, if I receive data like:

```
text: &lt;p&gt;Example&lt;/p&gt;
```

How do I force handlebars to translate it and render it as normal HTML?

Comment: Most template languages assume the data is either encoded for the target output or is plain text that needs encoding. They don't come with "decode from arbitary encode" features.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to decode it first, then pass it to handlebars with triple brackets. I know a small tip to decode html entities with jQuery:

```
// encoded is "&lt;p&gt;Example&lt;/p&gt" in your example
var decoded = $('<textarea />').html(encoded).val();
// decoded should now return <p>Example</p>
```

Comment: +1 for using this nice hack to decode without the need of `.replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;').replace(/</g, '&lt;')`!

Comment: I don't mind voting up twice for this answer if I can.

Comment: While the answer is correct, It's better to not use the jQuery hack for decoding html entities. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715395/1259882 for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Handlebars provides helpers and write a custom helper like follows under **Handlebars_helpers.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('encodeMyString',function(inputData){
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(inputData);
});
```

and use this helper in your `.handlebar` files or `.hbs` files as follows

```
{{encodeMyString myHTMLData}}
```

Without help of Jquery you can use it any where inside your handlebars. 
Even you can use the helper to pass the data alone and which will return the data with prepended and appended tags.