# Post HTML encoded Form data to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms-view-engine

I'm currently using MVC 3 (WebForm view engine) and have a form that shows user comments.

If I have a comment which has an ampersand (&), `<%= Html.Textbox() %>` will encode it as `&amp;`. However, if the form is then posted to the server, ASP.NET kicks in thinking that the submitted content is malicious.

I find myself having to use [HTML decoding methods using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/84395) before the content is sent to the server.

I am able to get the results that I want, but I feel like I'm not doing this right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use special attribute to allow safe html tags to be posted by using `AllowHtml` attribute , you will define your model/viewmodel as following

```
public class Comment
{

       public int Id{get; set;}

       [AllowHtml] // Allow safe html tags
       public string Comment {get; set;}   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to modify the model.

Comment: you could use `[ValidateInput(false)]` on the controller but thats risky becvause it will allow everything and wont validate it

Comment: or lastly what you did , is encoding the result before sending it to the server