# How to unescape characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

I want to convert this string

```
&lt;p&gt;update this post&lt;/p&gt;
```

to

```
<p>update this post</p>
```

in Javascript.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Paul That one is focused on a specific entity, in addition to using jQuery. It was also asked later than the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create an element, set its `innerHTML` and get its `innerText`:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = '&lt;p&gt;update this post&lt;/p&gt; ';
console.log(element.innerText);
```

The result is:

```
"<p>update this post</p> "
```

Comment: This works fine for hardcoded values, but beware of using this for user input.

Comment: and, if you used jquery it would be as easy as this: `$('<div />').html('&lt;p&gt;update this post&lt;/p&gt; ').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
var text='&lt;p&gt;update this post&lt;/p&gt;';
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML=text;
alert(d.innerText || d.text || d.textContent);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use this method:

```
var param = '&lt;p&gt;update this post&lt;/p&gt'; 
unescape(param);
```

Comment: The `unescape`function (which is deprecated because it can't handle Unicode properly) doesn't work on that form of escaping.