# Is this how I should decode strings from server in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, json, encoding, antixsslibrary

I'm receiving JSON data from an ASP.NET web service that has been HtmlEncoded with Microsoft's AntiXSS library (`Encoder.HtmlEncode()`) and then returned as JSON via a jQuery Ajax call.

I am populating edit form inputs with this data like so: `$('descriptionTextBox').val(object.Description);`

Other times, I may just be appending it as Html to the page which displays the data as expected: `$('descriptionSpan').html(object.Description);`

Obviously, this resulted in the form inputs displaying encoded data if the string originally contained Html or characters that were encoded.  To decode the data for display in inputs, I am using the following:

```
function decodeHtml(encodedStr) {
    return $("<div/>").html(encodedStr).text();
}
```

like so `$('descriptionTextBox').val(decodeHtml(object.Description));`

Is this the proper way encoded data should be set on forms/inputs with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that's fine. For an alternative way to decode strings containing html entities please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/240324.

I personally like this method more, because it doesn't creates an html element just to decode a string, however it's nothing wrong with your method.

Comment: I had seen that question, noticed the accepted answer was doing what I was doing, and didn't think to look at the other answers.  Thanks.