# using font awesome on input field button text

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I want to use a font awesome class i.e. search glass

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/search/

i.e.

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i> fa-search
```

on a input field (Note its' to remain an input field)

```
<input class="aa_findaddress aa_button" type="button" value="Search">
```

Not sure how I can fit it in ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988373/how-do-i-add-a-font-awesome-icon-to-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Phrasing contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) is permitted as the content of `<button>` element.*

You could use [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag, as follows:

```
<button>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
</button>
```