# How to make a Ajax Submit Button with an html tag inside the label

Tags: html, ajax, yii

i want add fontawesome icon in ajaxsubmitbutton,

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Print Preview',
array('ma/select'),
array(  'success'=>'reloadGrid',
        'error'=>'js:function(data){
            alert("Please select checkbox");
            return false;
        }'),
array(  //'encodeLabel'=>false,
        'class'=>'btn btn-success',
        )); ?>
```

i have try to set encodeLabel to false, and try encode to false, all of them doesn't work, 
 does anyone know how to about that??? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `encodeLabel`? The problem is that FontAwesome stylesheets use `before` pseudo-elements to add icon.

`:after` and `:before` pseudo elements, they can only be put on container elements. Why? Because they are appended inside that particular element. `input` **is not** a container. `button` for instance **is** hence you can put them on.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton( '&#xf067; Print Preview ', $url, array(),
 array('encode'=>false)
)
```

And in CSS something like this:

```
input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: FontAwesome, 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

For further reference check this:
[How do I add a Font Awesome icon to input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988373/how-do-i-add-a-font-awesome-icon-to-input-field)

Comment: i have try from that answer, but doesn't work for ajaxsubmitbutton

Comment: Check and try updated answer then, this will generate a font awesome icon on `input`