# How to add an icon in a search box

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

Questions to cover:
How to add an icon in a search box / form
How to add an icon in an input field

I had the following issue whereby I could't get the FontAwesome fa-search icon to sit to the right of the input field / search box.

Here is an image of the form:
[A HTML search form on a website's header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RFyI.jpg)

Link to the form here (not evergreen):
https://www.themirrorman.co

Here is my original code:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #header-search-desktop-div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 180px;
      width: 450px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border: 1px solid #881d98;
      border-radius: 24px;
  }
  #header-search-desktop-div #header-search-fa {
      position: absolute;
      color: #7E7E7E;
      z-index: 100;
      font-size: 27px;
  }
  #header-search-desktop-div .fa-search {
      top: 5%;
      left: 1.5%;
      line-height: 0.8em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header-search-desktop-div">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="https://themirrorman.co/">
            <span id="header-search-fa" class="fa fa-search">
                <input id="header-search-desktop-input" name="product-search" type="text" value="" placeholder="Product Search…">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
            </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

The following code I received answers on and changed, it now works like in the above image link:

```css
#header-search-submit {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
padding: 0;
right: 15px;
top: 6px;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: FontAwesome;
color: #7B7B7B;
cursor: pointer;
background: 0;
border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-search-desktop-div">
<form id="header-search-form" role="search" action="https://themirrorman.co/" method="get">
<fieldset>
    <span class="text">
        <input id="header-search-desktop-span" style="border-radius: 24px;" type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="I am looking for..." />
        <input id="header-search-submit" type="submit" value="&#xf002;" name="post_type" />
    </span>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Once you get an answer to your question the website you linked will change, leaving the question irrelevant for future readers looking for an answer. Make sure your question remains relevant by adding a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Hi Andrei thanks for the feedback. I've now done as you've asked, please confirm if what I've done is good?

Comment: marking an answer as accepted is enough to tell everyone your issue is solved, you don't need to put it in the question. In general, taking out the particular and leaving only the bare necessary to understand and answer the question is one of the things that sets great questions apart from the rest. Because future readers spend less time understanding it. Thank you for adjusting your question and welcome to [so].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the code below which is inspired by this link:
[How do I add a Font Awesome icon to input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988373/how-do-i-add-a-font-awesome-icon-to-input-field/15988499#15988499)

```css
input[type="search"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Where fOO2 is the Unicode value for the fa-search icon -->

<input type="search"  placeholder="&#xf002 Search" >
```

Edit: 07/23/2020
I recently visited this question again and wanted to add an alternative solution. I basically copied the code for the Google search bar and added my own tweaks to it. From left to right the search bar consists of a label, an input and a button.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}


/* -----search-container styles----- */

.search-container {
  --searchbox-height: 44px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  min-width: 410px;
  width: var(--content-width);
}


/* -----searchbar styles----- */

.searchbar {
  background: white;
  cursor: text;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 584px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(32, 33, 36, .28);
  border-radius: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: var(--searchbox-height);
  position: relative;
}


/* -----search-input styles----- */

.search-input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  border-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin: auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: initial;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.search-input:focus {
  outline: transparent;
}

.search-input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* -----search-icon styles---- */

.search-icon-wrapper {
  padding: 0 24px;
  /* margin-right: 48px; */
}

.search-icon {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgZmlsbD0iIzVGNjM2OCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE1LjUgMTRoLS43OWwtLjI4LS4yN0E2LjQ3MSA2LjQ3MSAwIDAgMCAxNiA5LjUgNi41IDYuNSAwIDEgMCA5LjUgMTZjMS42MSAwIDMuMDktLjU5IDQuMjMtMS41N2wuMjcuMjh2Ljc5bDUgNC45OUwyMC40OSAxOWwtNC45OS01em0tNiAwQzcuMDEgMTQgNSAxMS45OSA1IDkuNVM3LjAxIDUgOS41IDUgMTQgNy4wMSAxNCA5LjUgMTEuOTkgMTQgOS41IDE0eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 16px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 24px;
}


/* -----search-microphone styles----- */

.search-microphone {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 21px 21px;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-inline-end: 16px;
  padding: 22px 12px 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 21px;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="searchbar">
    <label for="search-input" class="search-icon-wrapper">
    <div class="search-icon"></div>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="search-input" id="search-input" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">
    <button class="search-microphone"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've now amended this post and marked your answer as best.