# How can I enter in a double quote in ckEditor and have it display correctly with AngularJS ng-bind?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I am using the Insert plug-in with ckEditor. When I enter:

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

It's stored in my database as:

```
System.out.println(&ldquo;Hello World!&rdquo;);
```

When I show this on my HTML page using `<div data-ng-bind-html="text"></div>` it shows as:

```
System.out.println(&ldquo;Hello World!&rdquo;);
```

Can someone help and tell me how I can make it output to the page without the &ldquo?

Comment: Have tried just `data-ng-bind`?  That should render the html.

Comment: ng-bind I think got replaced with ng-bind-html in 1.2 rc2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) for displaying or add a [angular $formatter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) and resolve the html entities with the help of the answers to [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode).