# IE cant print response header (from ajax) as utf8

Tags: javascript, utf-8, header

I use PJAX to change pages on my site and for every new page I send a `Response Header` with a new a `Page-Title` header. This header contains can contain åäö, and IE outputs this incorrectly. In IE's Developer Tools I can see the `Page-Title` response without problem, but when I use `document.title = ...` to update the title it displays wrong.

My response header looks like this:
`Page-Title: Mårtensson`

UTF8 is confirmed, I can see `Content-Type: text/html; chartset=UTF-8` in both IE's and Chrome's Dev Tools.

This is how I update the title:

```
$.ajax({
    url: State.url,
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', true); 
    },
    success: function(resp, status, xhr) { 
        document.title = xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title');
        // other code
    }
});
```

This works in Chrome but in IE it outputs as `MÃ¥rtensson`. If I use `decodeURIComponent(escape(document.title = xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title')));` it outputs fine in IE, but then in Chrome I get `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`.

How can I get it to work in both browsers?

---

## Solution

I fixed it by running [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the string before I output it as a response header. I then [decode the string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/397195) before I set it as title.

```
document.title = decodeEntities(xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) that specifically deals with this issue. Basically, keep in mind that if you use UTF-8 characters in a HTTP header field, you are on your own and different browsers will have different behavior.

If you really need to use a header for this, you should use some kind of escaping (server side) and unescaping (client side) to make your title fit into the ISO-8859-1 charset.

Comment: There may be also a problem with displaying non-ASCII characters in `document.title`, no matter where data came from.

Comment: Thanks. I now run `htmlentities` on the string before i output it to the header and then decode it with javascript as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/397195 described.