# JavaScript - decodeURI to render as HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem that has been bugging me and I cant seem to find a solution that works. I have a string that has come from a xml document in the following format.

```
var str="&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/ap131120.html&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_131120.jpg&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; alt=&quot;What are black hole jets made of?&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt; What are black &amp;amp; hole jets made of?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br clear=&quot;all&quot;/&gt;";
```

I have used

```
var dec = decodeURI(str);
```

The output I wish to render as HTML and not see the output which I get below.

```
<p><a href="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/ap131120.html"><img src="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_131120.jpg" align="left" alt="What are black hole jets made of?" border="0" /></a> What are black &amp; hole jets made of?</p><br clear="all"/>
```

I have tried sending this decoded data to the HTML document with

```
document.write(dec)
```

and

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=dec;
```

Comment: what's wrong with that output? It looks okay to me. Also I don't think that this is the output of decodeURI...?

Comment: Youu are correct the decodeURI was not changing the string at all. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually replace all entities

```
function unescape(str){
    return str.replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
              .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
              .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
              .replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
}

var str="&lt;p&gt;&lt;.../&gt;";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = unescape(str);
```

Comment: I think its not a efficient way you have to provide every entity if appears in string?

Comment: You need to escape `<>"&` to make it "valid" html. Other entities are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and [html/xml entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). They are two different encoding methods. For example, in URL encoding, `<` is encoded as `%3C`, but for entities, it is `&lt;`

If you run a `console.log(decodeURI(str))`, you will notice most things like `&quot` stay unchanged, because `decodeURI()` is not suppose to decode html entities.

To solve this problem, you can either have the xml return the correct URL encoding:

```
var str="%3Cp%3E%3Ca href=%22http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/ap131120.html%22%3E%3Cimg src=%22http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_131120.jpg%22align=%22left%22alt=%22What are black hole jets made of?%22border=%220%22/%3E%3C/a%3E What are black hole jets made of?%3C/p%3E%3Cbr clear=%22all%22/%3E";
```

Or you can use [a piece of Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/841435) to decode the entities what you have right now.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4ZR/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [JavaScript Library](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) which might help you with this. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHuHQ/).

```
var str="&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/ap131120.html&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_131120.jpg&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; alt=&quot;What are black hole jets made of?&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt; What are black &amp;amp; hole jets made of?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br clear=&quot;all&quot;/&gt;";

$("#output").html(_.unescape(str));
```