# How to assign HTML entities in Polymer element definition?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

Alternative question version: **How to prevent HTML entities from being escaped, when added in the Polymer element definition?**

So assume this simplified example (all includes of polymer libraries are added in the real code):

**element definition**

```
<polymer-element name="x-test" attributes="val">
  <template>
    <div>{{shownVal}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer( 'x-test', {
      shownVal: '',
      valChanged: function(){
        this.shownVal = this.val + ' &amp;';
      }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**element usage**

```
<x-test val="123"></x-test>
```

This will result in an output like this:

> 123 &amp;

**Version**: Polymer 0.1.2

**What do I need to change/add to have an output like `123 &`?**

Or is this some kind of bug, I should let the Polymer guys know about?

I know, that I could add the entity in the `<template>` and this would work, but I have some code, which modifies the input attributes and needs to use entities.

---

Note: If using the element like this

```
<x-test val="123 &amp;"></x-test>
```

everything renders fine.

Comment: Have your tried ```this.shownVal = this.val + ' &';```

Comment: @HBP `&amp;` was just an example here. I want to insert other HTML entities and I don't want to use their character representation.

Comment: OK, assuming the answer to my first question is "yes" then that would imply that the processing of ```valChanged``` is converting any HTML special chars like & and < into their entity coding. See then answer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode if you absolutely have to pass HTML entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

- [Custom filters](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/225#issuecomment-31874715) (not documented yet)

  ```
  encodeEntities: function(value) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.shownVal;
    return div.innerHTML;
   }
  ```
- Use [automatic node finding](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) and set the `.innerHTML` of some container.

  ```
  this.$.container.innerHTML = this.shownVal;
  ```

Demo showing both of these: http://jsbin.com/uDAfOXIK/2/edit

Comment: A question: Is this implicit conversion of HTML entities considered a feature or a bug? If feature, I think it should be documented somewhere (FAQ?).

Comment: The solution given here doesn't work for me. Perhaps things are different as there is a different version of Polymer around now?