# How to display html inside template?

Tags: html, templates, polymer

I have polymer-element:

[example](http://jsbin.com/ribezobo/2/edit)

By default templates is not allowed to insert html.

[This sample is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/how-to-assign-html-entities-in-polymer-element-definition), because it's not allowed to insert html.
Maybe exists the way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is through a `*Changed` watcher and setting the `.innerHTML` the node:

```
<div id="div"></div>

labelChanged: function() {
  this.$.div.innerHTML = this.label;
}
```

Then, for the `<template repeat>` case, wrap things up in a custom element that follows the similar pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22208332.

Answer (score 2):

```
<element inner-h-t-m-l="{{prop}}"></element>
```

works for Polymer 2. Source: https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/issues/57