# Is there a way to allow safe html data bind in polymer?

Tags: polymer

Is there a way to allow data bind with html rendering in polymer?

For example in AngularJS there is the "ng-html-bind" directive that does the job. I am searching something similar.

Here it follows an example of where I am willing to use it.

```
<core-tooltip>
    <core-icon icon="info-outline" size="30"></core-icon>
    <div tip>
       {{box.description}}
    </div>
</core-tooltip>
```

Otherwise any suggestion on how to do it differently? 
I am loading this data from a json file and I am searching for a general way to allow "safe" html rendering (against XSS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered a couple of times:

- [How to inject HTML into a template with polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199662/how-to-inject-html-into-a-template-with-polymer/22208332#22208332)
- [How to display html inside template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311574/how-to-display-html-inside-template/22311788#22311788)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the accepted answer, I associated an id to my tooltip div:

```
<div id="tipContent" tip>
    {{box.description}}
</div>
```

Then made my element listen to the *box* changes:

```
Polymer("nautes-box",{
  boxChanged: function(){
      this.$.tipContent.innerHTML = this.box.description.chunk(40).join("<br /><br />");
  }
});
```

I hope this answer will eventually be useful :)