# Is it possible to inject HTML into a polymer component via an attribute?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I'm using one of the core polymer components that basically has:

```
<polymer-element attributes="label">
    <div>{{label}}</div>
```

as part of the source.  I'd like to inject some HTML into this so that it ultimately renders as:

```
<div>Item <small>Description</small></div>
```

Is there any way to do this without copying the entire component (which is basically impossible considering the dependency chain)?

Answer (score 2):

*Polymer doesn't allow setting HTML inside `{{}}` expressions because it's a known XSS outlet. However, there are ways around it ([1](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#setinnerHTML), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/how-to-assign-html-entities-in-polymer-element-definition)).*

I'm not sure there's a great way around this issue but I found something that works. You want to extend the element but also need to modify its shadow dom because of the `.innerHTML` limitation. Taking [paper-button as an example](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/blob/master/paper-button.html#L72:L79), it has an internal `{{label}}`. You could extend the element, drill into its shadow dom, and set `.innerHTML` of the container where `{{label}}` is set. React to label changing (`labelChanged`) and call `this.super()`:

```
<polymer-element name="x-el" extends="paper-button">
  <template>
    <shadow></shadow>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-el', {
      labelChanged: function() {
        // When label changes, find where it's set in paper-button
        // and set the container's .innerHTML.
        this.$.content.querySelector('span').innerHTML = this.label;

        // call paper-button's labelChanged().
        this.super();
      }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ripufoqu/1/edit

Problem is that it's brittle and requires you to know the internals of the element you're extending.