# Converting HTML Entities from JSON to String

Tags: polymer

I'm using polymer and I'm new to it (just started using it today) and I have some troubles displaying data coming from JSON like`&nbsp;` , `&#8217;`, `&#8220` etc.

**HTML**

```
<news-card>        
    <h1>{{summary.title}}</h1>
    <img src="{{summary.thumbnail}}"></img>
    <span>{{summary.published}}</span>
    <p>{{summary.summary}}</p>
</news-card>
```

**Ex. JSON:**

```
{
 title: '&#8217; This is a title',
 thumbnail: 'test.jpg',
 published: 'October 15'
 summary: '&#8220; &nbsp; &nbsp;'
}
```

**Ex. Output:**

```
&#8217; This is a title
October 15
&#8220; &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

Comment: The entity in the title should end in a semi-colon: `&#8217;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used custom filters to display the desired output.

**HTML**

```
<news-card>

    <h1>{{summary.title | encodeEntities}}</h1>
    <img src="{{summary.thumbnail}}"></img>
    <span>{{summary.published}}</span>

    <p>{{summary.summary | encodeEntities}}</p>
</news-card>
```

**Script**

```
Polymer('your-polymer-element-name', {
      encodeEntities: function(value) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = value;
        return div.innerHTML;
      }
  });
```

Sources:

[Polymer -  Expressions: Custom Filters](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#custom-filters)

[Stackoverflow - How to assign HTML entities in Polymer element definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/how-to-assign-html-entities-in-polymer-element-definition)