# Converting HTML tags from JSON-String into real HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, json, html-parsing, polymer, web-component

I created a custom Element wich gets data from a JSON file:

```
<polymer-element name="view-component" attributes="number">
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_style.css" type="text/css">

    <core-ajax auto
    response="{{data}}"
    on-core-response="{{ajaxHandler}}"

    url="http://www.test.com/json/{{number}}"; 

    handleAs="json"></core-ajax>

    <div class="showbox">

    <p><b>entry:</b> {{data.entry| encodeEntities}}</p>
 </template>
```

The data.entry String looks like this: `<p>MyBrand&trade; is <b>very<\b> nice <\p>`

After finding this Question:

[Converting HTML Entities from JSON to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385986/converting-html-entities-from-json-to-string)

my String looks like this:  `<p>`MyBrand™ is `<b>`very`<\b>` nice `<\p>`

But How do I parse the actual Elements in that String and add them to my Custom Element?

Here is my JavaScript Code so far:

```
Polymer('view-component', {

  encodeEntities: function(value) {

    console.log(value);
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = value;
    console.log(div.childNodes[0]);
    return div.innerHTML;

  },
```

My console log `console.log(div.childNodes[0]);` puts out a DOM-Tree which looks perfect!
But when I want to return it to the component, the Browser renders : `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` instead of attaching the DOM to my element.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer escapes injected data by default for security considerations. (see [Advanced Topics – Data Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html)). You will thus have to use the `injectBoundHtml` method. To do this, you should give your `<p>` tag an id  and add the content using `injectBoundHtml`, for example in the `ready` callback:

```
Polymer({
  ready: function() {
    this.injectBoundHTML('<b>entry:</b> {{data.entry}}', 
                         this.$.your_paragraph_id);
  }
});
```

Two asides:

1. You don't need to specify the name of the element in the `Polymer()` call if you are including the script within the `<polymer-element>` tag.
2. I think you're missing the declaration of the `data` attribute, unless you've put it in the publish object or something.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Unfortunatly I cannot change the JSON output! Is there any other (no Polymer) way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the JSON model has to change for this to work (there's no need for that). The only thing that you need to do differently is to use injectBoundHTML when creating your custom element.