# Get html code in json-object from php using core-ajax in Polymer

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, polymer

I want to return data with json from a php-script. The data is containing html tags but when I try to use the data as html I can see the "tags".

HTML-tags will be displayed as: `<h1>hello</h1>` and not:

## hello

I am using the `<core-ajax>` tag in Polymer

```
<core-ajax id="ajax" auto url="php/directory_json.php" on-core-response="{{docsLoaded}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
```

Javascript

```
var template = document.querySelector('template[is="auto-binding"]');
var docs = []
template.docsLoaded = function() {
    this.docs = this.$.ajax.response.slice(0);
}
```

HTML

```
<template repeat="{{doc in docs}}"><div>{{doc.content}}</div></template>
```

PHP

```
$my_html = array(array('uid'=>'0', 'content'=>'<h1>hello</h1>'));
echo json_encode($my_html);
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Edit:** It seems like you can't just put out a variable with html-code. You need to apply it in the element with `innerHTML()` (`$.html()` with jquery).

Now I have stumbled upon another problem, I can't target my element with its ID, it says "undefined".

HTML

```
<template repeat="{{doc in docs}}">
    <div id="div-content-"{{doc.uid}}></div>
    {{myfunction(doc.uid, doc.content)}}
</template>
```

JavaScript

```
myfunction = function(id, content){
    $('#div-content-'+id).html(content);
}
```

It seems like the element isn't "applied" to the html until the whole loop is completed? Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the htmlentities function:

```
$my_html = array(array('uid'=>'0', 'content'=>htmlentities('<h1>hello</h1>')));
```

this way the `<` tag opener will become `&lt;` and will not be interpreted

Comment: The problem is that i want the html tag to be displayed as html! This will only show me &lt;h1&gt;hello&lt;/h1&gt;

Comment: hmm...maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/how-to-assign-html-entities-in-polymer-element-definition

Comment: Thank you, it seems like you can't just put out a variable with html-code. You need to apply it in the element with either $.html() or innerHTML(). Sadly I have another issue right now, it seems like the element is not defined until the loop is done. So when I try to reach my element it says "undefined" :/

Comment: About "when I try to reach my element it says "undefined", I just asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116154/how-can-i-know-that-template-repeat-has-finished