# How to render html entity symbols in a dom-repeat?

Tags: polymer-2.x

I ask this questions because all existing solutions which are existing like:

- [polymer issue 432](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/432)
- [polymer issue 1331](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1331)
- [entities-in-polymer-element-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/how-to-assign-html-entities-in-polymer-element-definition)

for example are outdated and/or not working any longer.

I have a simple `dom-repeat` statement:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
    <a target="_blank" href="[[item.url]]">[[item.label]]</a>
</template>
```

As you can see here im showing a list of urls. When the datasource now contains html entities:

```
this.push('items', {
    label: '&copy; Google 2018',
    url: 'http://www.google.de'
});
```

The entities wont render:

```
&copy; Google 2018
```

My `<a>` tags wont have any id's and I also dont know which datasource item has an html entity and which not. So how am I supposed to render html entities with `Polymer version 2.5.0`?

Comment: I've not tried `lit-html` (https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html), but maybe that would work for this case. You might put the question to @justinfagnani.

Comment: I tried this for a couple of hours now and still have no idea how to solve this using `lit-html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to assign each item in the `dom-repeat` a unique `id`, then set the `innerHTML` on that item after the render.

In the following code (and [this pen](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/dmGPww?editors=1001)) I set an `id` with `_assign(index)`. In the `ready()` method, I call `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender` to wait for all items to draw, then set the anchors' `innerHTML`'s in the same manor using a `querySelector` on that `id`:

```
<dom-module id="show-entity">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
      <a target="_blank" id="[[_assign(index)]]" href="[[item.url]]"></a><br>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * `show-entity`
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/
     *
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     * @demo demo/index.html
     */
    class ShowEntity extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'show-entity'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          items: {
            type: Array,
            value: () => { return []; }
          }
        }
      }
      ready() {
        super.ready();
        this.items.push({
          label: '&copy; Google 2018',
          url: 'http://www.google.de'
        },{
          label: '&#167; Google 2018',
          url: 'http://www.google.de'
        });


        Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender( this, () => {
          this.items.forEach((el, idx) => {
            let id = this._assign(idx);
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#'+id).innerHTML = el.label;
          });
        })
      }

      _assign(index) {
        return 'foo'+index;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(ShowEntity.is, ShowEntity);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Note that you must import `polymer/lib/utils/render-status.html` to use [`Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.RenderStatus#function-Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender).