# Angular JS - How can I sanitize HTML in a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to sanitize HTML in the controller as I'm trying to update the document.title dynamically with the title of the post. (I know that for SEO purposes this isn't recommended but I need to use it here)

```
$scope.prevTitle = "dynamic title gets pulled in here &amp;"
document.title = $scope.prevTitle
```

For this example, I've just used a random HTML entity. I've tried the parseAsHtml method from the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#parseAsHtml) but I'm having no luck. I tried the following:

```
document.title = $sce.parseAsHtml($scope.prevTitle)
```

But no luck. The documentation suggests it needs to be used within a function. Any suggestions on how I would acheive this?

A console log of the above ( console.log($sce.parseAsHtml($scope.prevTitle)) ) would return:

```
function (b,c){return e.getTrusted(a,d(b,c))}
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that you can't put HTML into a `document.title`, you'll need to [HTML decode it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Answer (score 2):

`$sanitize` can be used as @acg pointed out. Alternatively, you can use it directly with the `ng-bind-html` directive where it automatically sanitizes the output variable before rendering the output.

The above point is not quite clear in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize), but there is a fairly extensive example in it with which you can play in pluncker.

Please also bear in mind that `ngSanitize` is an external module and you need to explicitly load `angular-sanitize.js` or include it in your js minification.

Answer (score 1):

Use $sanitise and trustAsHtml instead

First of all inject 'ngSanitize' in your module

Now in your controller, just add

```
$scope.prevTitle = "dynamic title gets pulled in here &amp;"
document.title = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.prevTitle)
```

Comment: Thanks but this appears to do the opposite or just have no effect at all? I've injected ngSanitize in my module a while ago.

Comment: You do not need `$sce.trustAsHtml` for `ngSanitize` to work. On the contrary, this allows a non-escaped HTML string to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sanitize the html returned, I would think it would be as simple as using the [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service:

```
document.title = $sanitize($sce.parseAsHtml($scope.prevTitle))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this just prevents the title from updating at all. Console gives me $sanitize is not defined even though I've defined it as a dependency

Comment: @LT86 have you included the `angular-sanitize.js` file? @acg, why would you need to `parseAsHtml` before sanitizing?