# pass encoded php json to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, backbone.js

I have a problem with my application made in PHP and javascript.

I have an ajax call to a function php that get values from database.
I retrieve many records with fields and inside it I have a field called `description` with a value like this:

```
<p><strong>TEST IT</strong></p><p>non gras<span style="color: rgb(192, 145, 0);">sett</span>o  </p>
```

After I encode the json, get it in javascript and print it. But the result is:

```
TEST+IT

non+grassetto++
```

My code is something like this:

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({   
                url: site_url_database, 
                type: "GET", 
                async: true,
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 30000,
                success: function(data) {
                    _.each(data.hotel, function(d, index_d) {
                        data.hotel[index_d].description = decodeURIComponent(d.description);
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {

                }
            })
```

PHP function to get field description:

```
....
$hotel_array['description'] = urlencode($row->hotel_description);
....
//encode array to return
$hotel_array = json_encode($hotel_array);
echo($hotel_array);
```

After I print it in javascript (Backbone) but if I make a `console.log()` I get this:

```
TEST+IT

    non+grassetto++
```

How can I print it well?

Thanks

P.S. I can't change the method of working so I need an ajax call a function php and print it in Backbone/javascript I only need to encode and decode well

I have already tried in php:

```
$hotel_array['description'] = addslashes(htmlentities($row->hotel_description));
```

In javascript I have tried to use:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kvz/phpjs/master/functions/url/urldecode.js

[HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode/9609450#9609450)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's `decodeURIComponent()` does not remove the `+` characters added by PHP's `urlencode()`; it expects space to be encoded as `%20`, not `+`:

```
$hotel_array['description'] = urlencode($row->hotel_description);

php > echo $hotel_array['description'];
%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ETEST+IT%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Enon+gras%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%28192%2C+145%2C+0%29%3B%22%3Esett%3C%2Fspan%3Eo++%3C%2Fp%3E
```

Then, in Javascript:

```
>js s = '%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ETEST+IT%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Enon+gras%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%28192%2C+145%2C+0%29%3B%22%3Esett%3C%2Fspan%3Eo++%3C%2Fp%3E';
>js decodeURIComponent(s);
<p><strong>TEST+IT</strong></p><p>non+gras<span+style="color:+rgb(192,+145,+0);">sett</span>o++</p>
```

As you can see, the `+` characters remain in the decoded string.

Instead you can use `rawurlencode()` which follows RFC 3986 and encodes spaces as `%20`.

```
php > $s = rawurlencode('<p><strong>TEST IT</strong></p><p>non gras<span style="color: rgb(192, 145, 0);">sett</span>o  </p>');
php > echo $s;
%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ETEST%20IT%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Enon%20gras%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3A%20rgb%28192%2C%20145%2C%200%29%3B%22%3Esett%3C%2Fspan%3Eo%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E
```

Then in Javascript:

```
js> decodeURIComponent('%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ETEST%20IT%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Enon%20gras%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3A%20rgb%28192%2C%20145%2C%200%29%3B%22%3Esett%3C%2Fspan%3Eo%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E');
<p><strong>TEST IT</strong></p><p>non gras<span style="color: rgb(192, 145, 0);">sett</span>o  </p>
```

Alternatively, if you can not modify the PHP code, you can manually replace `+` with `' '`:

```
js> s = '%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ETEST+IT%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Enon+gras%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%28192%2C+145%2C+0%29%3B%22%3Esett%3C%2Fspan%3Eo++%3C%2Fp%3E';
js> decodeURIComponent(s).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
<p><strong>TEST IT</strong></p><p>non gras<span style="color: rgb(192, 145, 0);">sett</span>o  </p>
```

Comment: Return me this error when I parse json string:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 23447 of the JSON data, but I have seen that it can be a good way

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the PHP is stripping the HTML tags before passing it to the browser. Check to make sure that there is no `strip_tags()` function in your PHP function before encoding it.