# Issues with PHP echo into a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the same line of code to echo a link onto my page in two locations and getting different results. One is inside an < a > tag and the other is inside a < script > tag. Below are the two excerpts of code (from the same tpl file) and the results:

```
<a href="<?php echo $links['current_path']['href']; ?>" role="button"><?php echo $btn['text']; ?></a>
```

Results in:

```
<a href="index.php?route=module/jw/list&token=a4c693a4e38916fc03af23ad4fe17188" role="button">Filter</a>
```

However in the script tag I have

```
url = "<?php echo $links['current_path']['href']; ?>"
```

And my result is

```
 url = "index.php?route=module/jw/list&amp;token=a4c693a4e38916fc03af23ad4fe1"
```

Notice the '&' after the route parameter. It is displaying the html code when I echo it inside the script tag. I know I can convert it in the second instance, but I am curious as to why I would need to. Why is the same php command making the symbol echo differently in various parts of the source code?

Comment: Did you take that HTML from the source code or a DOM inspector? I'd imagine that your original string has `&amp;` in it as HTML and your DOM inspector is simplifying the view for you.

Comment: @pbaldauf — Why? It's HTML encoded not URL Encoded.

Comment: @Quentin: I am using a DOM inspector, but the link works fine when clicked but javascript location = url; does not

Comment: — That's the issue then. Your URL has already been converted from text to HTML, so it works fine in an HTML attribute but not in JavaScript. The best approach for dealing with that is to go to whereever you are getting the URL from and convert it to text there. Then convert it to HTML only when you are about to insert it into an HTML document.

Comment: Quentin: Thank you for helping me better understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&amp;` is a HTML entity - your browser parses and displays it. Some similar questions about decoding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode). Have you tried [html_entity_decode():](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

> html_entity_decode — Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

So

```
url = "<?php echo html_entity_decode($links['current_path']['href']); ?>"
```

Comment: Yes, and that does work. i was trying to understand why I would need to use that in a javascript tag and not in a standard link tag

Comment: That is how the browser/clients should handle these elements. Quoting http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata: Although the STYLE and SCRIPT elements use CDATA for their data model, for these elements, CDATA must be handled differently by user agents. Markup and entities must be treated as raw text and passed to the application as is. The first occurrence of the character sequence "</" (end-tag open delimiter) is treated as terminating the end of the element's content. In valid documents, this would be the end tag for the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php function [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo html_entity_decode($links['current_path']['href']); ?>" role="button"><?php echo $btn['text']; ?></a>
```