# How to get jQuery UI Autocomplete to ignore HTML entities

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Trying to get jQuery UI Autocomplete to work with data labels that may have entities in them, such as a hyphen ( - ).

I extended the function so that what shows in the suggestion list works and shows the character instead of the entity code, but cannot figure out how to make it do the same when the item is chosen and it populates the text field.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        var url = SQMSAutocomplete.url + "?action=sqms_auto_search";
        $( "#sqms-auto-search" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 3,

            select: function(event, ui){
               console.log(ui.item.link)
                // window.location = ui.item.url
             }
        })
        .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
              .append( item.label )
              .appendTo( ul );
          };
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Does that make sense?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by decoding the HTML entities before assigning the value of the `<input />` to the desired string.

Here's a simple example:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.value = $('<div />').html(ui.item.label).text();
}
```

*All credit for decoding HTML entities with JavaScript goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796718/497356)*. Be aware of the usual disclaimers about decoding HTML entities this way: you are opening yourself up to possible XSS vulnerabilities.

The "gotcha" here is that you *must* prevent the default action of the `select` event, which is to put the `label` or `value` inside of the input. Here we're overriding that behavior and decoding the text first.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/822fbwef/

Comment: Sweet thanks, this totally worked. Can you tell me 'how' it works though? What is that div doing... I would think that would add a div into the text field?

Comment: @thatryan: So that piece of code is creating a `<div></div>` that's not attached to the DOM. Then it's setting the HTML of that `div` to the item label, which is going to decode the HTML entities in the string. Finally, the text of the `div` (which is the decoded string) is retrieved using jQuery's `.text()` function

Comment: Ah, so it is just creating a "shadow" element to use for manipulation, but not actually putting it anywhere?

Comment: @thatryan: Yep, that's pretty much it!

Comment: Amazing solution, thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could decode the entities in the labels by using a function for the `source` option. That should take care of both issues. That is, you wouldn't have to override the `._renderItem()` function in that case.

```
$("#sqms-auto-search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function(items) {
            response($.map(items, function(item) {
                return $('<span></span>').html(item.label).text();
            });
        });
    },
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 3
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1wddvnj/)

Comment: Yep, this is a good option too and you avoid some duplicate work