# ng-bind-html get first letter of html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-filters

I am having a situation where i am using `ng-bind-html` for  html binding.
I would like to get the first charactor of html content excluding the html tags.
**Below is my sample code.**

```
<span class="first-letter">{{firstLetter}}</span>
            <div id="myDiv" ng-CLoak data-ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(data.ContentDescription)" class="{{currentFont}}"></div>
```

**my html string would look like following**

```
<p><span>hii my content</span></p>
the starting and ending tags are un predictable.
```

i would like to get first letter "h" not "<"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _I would like to get the first charactor of html_ i guess you forgot to add this in the question. Have you tried anything? We don't know what? Where?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978281/how-to-httputility-htmldecode-in-javascript/33978327#33978327

Comment: can you add controller code too in-order to know your real problem because I tried normally then I got the expected output.If you would share your full code it will be easy to sort out the problem with same approach.

Comment: "the starting and ending tags are un predictable". I think the question is not properly asked OP donot wants the the first letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the browser strip html for you using the `textContent` property

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

and since you are interested only in that first letter, than you probably don't need the `ng-bind-html` :)

In case you want to highlight that first letter, then use CSS :first-letter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-letter

Comment: @Jai Yes, I know. And what? The function only uses dom fragment, it was never appended to the real DOM, so this is imho perfectly OK even in Angular

Comment: @Jai it could cause problems only when run outside of browser environment ... which I do not expect

Answer (score 1):

You can remove HTML tags and simply access first letter as we do in an array like this.

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
,   body = "<p><span>hii my content</span></p>"
,   result = body.replace(regex, "");
console.log(result[0]);
```

**Using jQuery**

```
console.log($('<p><span>hii my content</span></p>').text()[0]);
```

It will give you "h"

Answer (score 1):

if your contet

```
<p class="first-letter"><span>hii my content</span></p>
```

then

```
$(".first-letter").text().substring(0,1)
```

would return you the first letter no matter how many levels of nesting are there within the class .first-letter