# unescape() function from underscore.js not working

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, decoding

I need to decode html entities such as: `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&#96;` and `&#x27;`.

As recommended in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode), I was trying to use `_.unescape()` from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) for this task.

However, `unescape()` doesn't seem to have any effect. When I call it e.g. on the following string, it just returns the string itself:

```
const line = 'Tweag I&#x2F;O | Paris, France &amp Berlin, Germany | Full-time. Give us a shout at jobs@tweag.io!'
```

To verify, you can go to [JSBin](https://jsbin.com) and paste the following code:

```
const line = 'Tweag I&#x2F;O | Paris, France &amp Berlin, Germany | Full-time. Give us a shout at jobs@tweag.io!'
console.log(line)

const decodedLine = unescape(line)
console.log(decodedLine)
```

Don't forget to add the `underscore.js` library by selecting it from the dropdown that appears when you hit the `Add library` button.

#### Update

As noted in @DanPrince's answer, `unescape()` only decodes a limited set of characters:

`&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&#96;`, `&#x27;`

But then, changing my line from the example above to the following still doesn;t work (even though this time I use `&#x27;` and `&amp;`):

```
const line = `'Tweag I&#x27;O | Paris, France &amp; Berlin, Germany | Full-time. Give us a shout at jobs@tweag.io!'`
```

#### Final Update

I solved my problem by using a different library. Instead of `underscore.js`, I am now using [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) which provides *exactly* the functionality I was looking for.

Now, I can just call `decode(line)` and *all* html entities get properly translated. I will be following up on the answers to this question however and accept the answer that explains why `unescape()` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: D'oh. Is this as simple as `unescape` vs `_.unescape`?

Comment: argh... yeah that does work in jsbin! sorry, I'm a js newbie and am never sure about these subtleties!

Comment: Not at all, I should have spotted it before. The browser includes a native [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) function for decoding URI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-160) for underscore, everything is translated through the following maps.

```
var escapeMap = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#x27;',
  '`': '&#x60;'
};
var unescapeMap = _.invert(escapeMap);
```

The two escaped entities in your string are `&#x2F;` and `&amp`, neither of which appear in the escape map. You can fix `&amp;` by adding a semicolon.

Whilst it's not particularly efficient, you could use the [answer suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912522/1088797).

Also, I'm getting the expected behaviour when I use `_.unescape` in jsbin, whereas I think your code uses the native `unescape` function.

Comment: thanks for the hint about the mapped characters! but strangely it doesn't work with any of those either... I changed the string I am testing to `'Tweag I&#x27;O | Paris, France &amp; Berlin, Germany | Full-time. Give us a shout at jobs@tweag.io!'`. in that version I have the `&amp;` as well as `'&#x27;`, but in my JSBin it's still not working...