# Javascript code for currency filter in AngularJS not working with custom symbols

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, currency-formatting

I have the following custom filter which either returns a "Not Available" string if the input is equal to zero or returns the input after applying a custom currency symbol on it (In this case, the rupee symbol). Here is the code:

```
(function(){

   angular.module('TestApp')
   .filter('availability', function($filter){
        return function(input){
            if(input == null){
              return "Not Available";
            }
            var test = $filter('currency')(input,"&#8377",0);
            return test;
        }
   });

})();
```

However, the desired result is not achieved. Instead the raw string for the currency symbol is being printed in front of the input. I have used the same currency symbol in my HTML code as shown below and it works:

```
{{value.Charge | currency:"&#8377;":0}}
```

Am I missing something obvious? If not, is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$filter('currency')(input,"&#8377",0);` inside the custom filter, "&#8377" is just a string. It is never decoded into the corresponding HTML entity.

If you pass it into the filter from the HTML, it will work fine as the HTML decodes it before it reaches the filter.

Otherwise, if you want to hard-code the value in your JavaScript, you'll need to decode it yourself. There are a few examples on SO which are easy to find such as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/3894163) which I've used below for the hard-coded example.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.amount = 32;
  })
  .filter('availability', function($filter) {
    return function(input, symbol) {
      console.log(symbol);
      if (input == null) {
        return "Not Available";
      }
      var test = $filter('currency')(input, symbol, 0);
      return test;
    }
  })
  .filter('hardcoded', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
      if (input == null) {
        return "Not Available";
      }
      var test = $filter('currency')(input, decodeEntities("&#8377;"), 0);
      return test;
    }
  });

// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode/9609450#9609450
var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

  <input ng-model="amount" />

  <p>
    Currency Filter: {{amount | currency:"&#8377;":0}}
  </p>
  <p>
    Custom Filter: {{amount | availability:"&#8377;"}}
  </p>
  <p>
    Hard-coded string in Custom Filter: {{amount | hardcoded}}
  </p>
</div>
```