# Javascript Apostrophe Decoding

Tags: javascript, string, decode, html-entities

I have a string javascript message like this one :

```
var message = "merci d&#39;ajouter";
```

And I want this text to be converted into this one (decoding) :

```
var result = "merci d'ajouter";
```

I don't want any replace method, i want a general javascript solution working for every caracter encoded. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Entity Decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Comment: It seems to me that any "general JavaScript" solution would involve replacement.  This is like asking for a shirt to be made but use no stitching.  On the other hand, decoding can be handled by the browser when setting the character type in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually possible in native JavaScript

Heep in mind that IE8 and earlier do not support `textContent`, so we will have to use `innerText` for them.

```js
function decode(string) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = string; 
    return typeof div.textContent !== 'undefined' ? div.textContent : div.innerText;
}

var testString = document.getElementById("test-string");
var decodeButton = document.getElementById("decode-button");
var decodedString = document.getElementById("decoded-string");
var encodedString = "merci d&#39;ajouter";
      
decodeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  decodedString.innerHTML = decode(encodedString); 
});
```

```html
<h1>Decode this html</h1>
<p id="test-string"></p>
<input type=button id="decode-button" value="Decode HTML"/>
<p id="decoded-string"></p>
```

An easier solution would be to use the `Underscore.js` library. This is a fantastic library that provides you with a lot of additional functionality.

Underscore provides an `_unescape(string)` function

> The opposite of escape, replaces &, <, >, ", ` and ' with their unescaped counterparts.

```
_.unescape('Zebras, Elephants &amp; Penguins');
=> "Zebras, Elephants & Penguins"
```

Comment: I'll take the first solution since i am not allowed to use external libraires :)