# Setting an element value using HTML entities

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-entities

I'm having an issue trying to set an input field's value when using HTML entities in that they are coming out literally as `&quot;` rather than `"`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
document.getElementById('inputSurname').setAttribute('value', 'test&quot;&quot;&quot;');
```

in which the output is `test&quot;&quot;&quot;` though I want the output to be `test"""`.

It doesn't look like a double-encoding issue since in the source code I am seeing it the same way I have set it here.

I know I could decode the value from its HTML entity format though this is something I want to avoid if possible for security.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can't have HTML in a form field, only text. It's the same reason why you can't set the value of an input to be bold via the value, only CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('inputSurname').value = 'test"""';
```

Or if you want to keep &quot:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('myText').value = replaceQuot('test&quot&quot&quot');
}
function replaceQuot(string){
    return string.replace('&quot', '""');
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am storing the value as `&quot;`, and because it's user input I don't really want to decode the HTML entities.

Comment: I've made a few tweaks since your answer and managed to get things working now. I've took the string I was using and replaced `&quot` with `\"` to avoid any issues from user input and this now looks normal in the input field - so I'll go ahead and mark your answer as the best solution for leading me to this :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use escape characters.

`document.getElementById("inputSurname").setAttribute("value", "test\"\"\"\"");`

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just write the new value as `'test"""'`.

For other characters however, I'm going to refer you to this answer: [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)