# Using &letter; notation in JavaScript doesn't write greek letters

Tags: javascript, html

When I set an input box value with the "value" attribute in HTML to a greek letter, it shows the greek letter correctly. But when I change the "value" attribute with JavaScript, it uses the "&letter;" format. What can I do so that JavaScript behaves just as HTML?

HTML: `<input type="text" id="input" value = "&epsilon;">` works fine.
JavaScript: `document.getElementById("input").value = "&epsilon;";` shows `&epsilon;` but not the greek letter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting an element value using HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308752/setting-an-element-value-using-html-entities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing occurs because of the way you're setting the input. Javascript is (correctly) treating your `&epsilon;` as an ordinary string, because you haven't told it that it's anything else.

If this were an element like `p`, or `span` or any other contextual text element, you could simply do

`myElem.innerHTML = "&epsilon;";`

However, since you want to set this to be the input's value, you can't use `innerHTML`, because it wouldn't make any sense. What you need to do is something like this.

```js
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

document.getElementById("myInput").value = htmlDecode("&epsilon;");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" value="">
```

The function I used was originally posted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/6133426). Be sure to read the rest of it, to see the other uses.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you have to parse it first, but it makes sense!