# How to remove all Unicode characters in my string so I can parse it perfectly?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, underscore.js

I have a JSON string as a result of an Ajax call and I want to parse the string, but my JSON string contains \u0030 or anything that starts with \u, and also those codes like `&nbsp` or `&thinsp` or any similar things that prevents `json.parse` from working. Is there a way to remove them or at least make `json.parse` understand those characters?

Comment: JSON.parse should not be affected by those unless the string is wrongly delivered to JS.  `c=new Option(); c.innerHTML = "blah &nbsp; blah \u0222"; c.text;` will realize the chars, the reverse order will escape them.

Comment: as @dandavis says, `JSON.parse` will work just fine with those characters - https://jsfiddle.net/pej5ded3/ - if you want to decode HTML entities see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode