# Unable to decode a UTF-8 string

Tags: javascript, xss

I need to decode this UTF-8 string: `j&#X41vascript`.

I have tried doing:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape('j&#X41vascript'))
```

which did not work, it returned the same string back.

Eventually, I would want to prevent the XSS attack originating from the attacker entering an input string like:

```
<IMG SRC=j&#X41vascript:alert('test2')>
```

Source: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Remember that you can't prevent XSS attacks with client-side JavaScript checks, as any user who knows their way around a browser can easily disable them. Use server-side validation for any data that is uploaded.

Comment: @gyre I am doing it server-side as well. This part is just for form validation. Your point is very much valid. :)

Comment: Have a look here: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/188/encode-and-decode-html-entities-using-pure-javascript

Comment: Are you trying to generate the image source from the string, or are you trying to detect dangerous data in existing HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/1003329 Probably, would be helpful.

Comment: @gyre Detect dangerous data in HTML.

Comment: @tulvit That did help :)

Comment: @RahulDesai I see the string printed as: "jAvascript", that to me seems very like what you're looking.

Comment: @tulvit It does not work if the input string is `<IMG SRC=j&#X41vascript:alert('test2')>`