# Google Script - special characters

Tags: google-apps-script

I have my database which contains some of the special characters (&, >, <, ") after I wrote a Google Script to display a table from my database by using deploy as Web App. The special characters as mentioned above change to & amp; & gt; & lt; & quot;

However some special characters for example $, #, @, !, ~, `, \, |, :, ;. They are displayed perfectly fine.

Could you please help?

I guess it is something to do with charsets ISO-8859 and UTF-8. But I don't know how to encode them. (https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp)

the script that I am working on is similar with the link provided below:
https://github.com/gkaldevrel/charts-in-apps-script/blob/master/GoogleFormsVisualizer.gs

Thank you

Boon

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/6153990).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Entity Decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Comment: risking off topic comment. The github link refers to UiApp which has been deprecated for a long time. You will be served well avoiding it. Its not maintained by google and could be one of the problem sources.