# UTF-8 symbol is converted when inserted to dom

Tags: javascript

I have a following problem, i am building app that uses data stream from ajax calls, the data that is coming is therefore escaped inside json string.

example: `1&deg;Set`

When i insert that data to DOM it is being converted like this: `1°Set`

I dont use any libraries like jQuery, pure Javascript.

I tried to store converted name also in another place but i cannot seem to convert it manually, i tried following functions:

```
var test = function(str) {
    console.log(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)) );
    console.log(decodeURIComponent(escape(str)) );
};

test('1&deg;Set');
```

It stays the same, does anyone have an idea how to convert it to a DOM like version?

Comment: what is the expected output for `test('<b>hi</b>')`  or `test('<script>alert(1)</script>')` ?

Comment: I don't understand this question? `&deg;` is the HTML symbol for the degree symbol. Obviously putting this into HTML will show the degree symbol, that's it's point. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: @Liam I understand the question is about converting a piece HTML source representing a string into the actual string

Comment: try using .textContent instead of innerHTML?

Comment: Why can't you just pass the Unicode character instead? - If you can't have you tried `&#176;` in place of `&deg;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a following problem, i am building app that uses data stream from ajax calls, the data that is coming is therefore escaped inside json string.
>
> example: `1&deg;Set`

Sounds like you're having a problem because your backend serves a JSON that looks like:

```
{
  "something": "1&deg;Set"
}
```

Instead of a string "1°Set", you're serving HTML source code that amounts to "1°Set". This looks very unnecessary. I cannot see a good reason of using HTML escaping inside JSON, unless you actually want your JSON to actually contain a part of HTML source (with formatting and everything), rather than just a string.

My suggestion: Let's keep it simple and instead serve something like:

```
{
  "something": "1°Set"
}
```

or equivalently escape it properly using JSON syntax:

```
{
  "something": "1\u00b0Set"
}
```

Now you'll JavaScript will receive a plain string that can be easily displayed, for example inside `element.textContent` or `element.value` or anywhere else. You won't even need any conversions.

Comment: if you're getting that JSON from somewhere else and you can't change the formatting, let me know, we'll look for something else. Starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode or https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Comment: I went through all this, because i have access to server i will modify the stream rather then be bothered by local conversions, thank You for the hint, its far better solution ;)