# Replace &amp; with only & when the url is called in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, iframe

I have an iframe with the sample format as below

```
<iframe src="http://alerts.solution.com/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=A46ba891cf8&sender=MOS&to=1234567890&message=MESSAGE"></iframe>
```

When this is called src url is getting changed like this:

```
<iframe src="http://alerts.solution.com/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=A46ba891cf8&amp;sender=MOS&amp;to=1234567890&amp;message=MESSAGE"></iframe>
```

How to remove `&amp;` and replace it with `&` after the url being called??
Thats leading to invalid data format and its not working as expected.

I tried several methods in javascript and php both. Nothing seemed to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode