# How convert html entities to tags

Tags: c#, html, webforms

I try use this block below in my Web Forms app:

```
string entitiesText = "&lt;p&gt;Example text &lt;/p&gt"
message.Text = entitiesText;
```

In this case in `message` label display " `<p>Example text</p>` ". How can I imput `entitiesText` to `message` label to display only text without html tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5796718

Comment: are you using php? or are you there only in javascript

Comment: @Edwin... I'm using C#

Comment: Do you want to *remove* the tags, or use them as *real* `<p>` tags?

Comment: use them as real <p> tags

Answer (score 0):

A `Label` control will escape the text so it will show the string as you see in the source.

A [`LiteralControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) can be used to inject HTML into the page (read: use the tags in the string as real tags).

However:

1. You need to have `<p>` in your string, not `&lt;p&gt;`
2. Any HTML is interpreted as such, including script tags input by your users.