# How to do databind two way in v-html?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an element div with atribute contenteditable="true". This div behaves like an element textarea.

```
<div v-on:keyup.enter="SendMensage" v-html="msg" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

my code:

```
data() {
     return {
        msg: '',
     }
},

methods: {
     enviaMensagem() {

        console.log(this.msg);

     }
}
```

My problem is that the databind does not work. What is typed in the div does not reflect on the variable. Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: You'll want `v-model` for two-way binding.

Comment: The `v-html` directive only binds one way. Why not use a textarea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to listen to changes of the element, because `v-model` only works on `<textarea>` or `<input>`. You can do this by using an `@input` listener.

The markup you get like this will be escaped. If you want to unescape it, you can use e.g. [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/3233827). Then, you actually have the markup right next to the pseudo-textarea field. So, why not using a `<textarea>` from begin with?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    msg: ''
  },
  methods: {
    typing: function(el) {
      this.msg = el.target.innerHTML;
    },
    submit: function() {
      console.log("Submitting: ", this.msg);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.output {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor">
  <div class="input" @input="typing" @keyup.enter="submit" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="output" v-html="msg"></div>
</div>
```