# How can I transform HTML to a different type in VueJS?

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following in my `Messages.vue` file:

```
<div class="msg" v-for="(msg, index) in messages" :key="index">
    <p class="msg-index">[{{index}}]</p>
    <p class="msg-subject" v-html="msg.subject"></p>
    <p class="msg-body" v-html="msg.body"></p>
    <input type="submit" @click="deleteMsg(msg.pk)" value="Delete" />
    <input type="submit" @click="EditMsg(msg.pk)" value="Edit" />
</div>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Messages",
  data() {
    return {
      subject: "",
      msgBody: "",
      messages: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchMessages();
  },
  ....
```

I want `msg-subject` and `msg-body` to change to `input` HTML elements, so the user can edit and submit them to be updated. I'm not really sure what's the best way to achieve this kind operation with VueJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do databind two way in v-html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376484/how-to-do-databind-two-way-in-v-html)

Comment: @HamzaMohamed no it’s not.

Comment: so let me get that straight, you are trying to change `<p>` to have an `<input>` tag when when user click it or click another button? and the input to be stored so it can be sent through the form?

Comment: When the user clicks another button, yes sir. The input needs to be sent in a POST request so yeah.

Comment: got it, but i got something that is not clear yet, that should be in html not text? the user should see and add `html` tags? or edit without tags?

Comment: Without tags, the message is plain text. It is meant to be short.

Comment: ok, now it is a bit complicated as you are willing to add html tags and then allow only the text part to be editable
so if you have a multiple tags, which one should be editable?

Comment: The input will not contain or shouldn't parse HTML tags. So `<p class="msg-body" v-html="msg.body"></p>` becomes something like `<input vlaue="msg.body"></input>`. I don't understand your comment about "which tags should be editable"...

Comment: ok, v-html is used to pass html codes, I thought when you added that in the Q, you meant that msg.body IS HTML code? but the `msg.body` is only pure text .. is that correct?

Comment: @HamzaMohamed yes sir.

Comment: writing the answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="msg" v-for="msg in messages" :key="msg.id">
          <p class="msg-index">[{{  msg.id }}]</p>
          <p class="msg-subject" v-text="msg.subject" 
            v-show="!msg.editing"></p>
          <input type="text" name="msg-subject"
            v-model="msg.subject" v-show="!!msg.editing">
          <p class="msg-body" v-text="msg.body" 
            v-show="!msg.editing"></p>
          <input type="text" name="msg-body" v-model="msg.body"
            v-show="!!msg.editing">
          <button @click="deleteMsg(msg.id)"> Delete </button>
          <button @click="editMsg(msg.id)"> Edit </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>




<script>
... // your usual component code
data(){
    return{
        messages:{
            ...
            editing:false,
                }
        }
    },
methods: {
    EditMsg(id){
    this.editing = true;
    // you can do a direct axios ajax or fetch to edit the updated value
    },
    deleteMsg(id){
    // you can do a direct axios ajax or fetch to delete value
    }

}
... // remaining component code
</script>
```

side notes:

**1 =>** it is not advised to use index as key, index has different uses, you can read about using [Index as a key is an anti-pattern here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and effort Hamza. I see two potential problems with this: 1. This will toggle the editing flag for ALL message elements, right? I want only the relevant message to transform. 2. I don't think `msg.body` can be passed to an AJAX call because it returns NULL when I console.log it. (perhaps I should write a separate `message` component (see my edits)

Comment: my bad, for number 1, if you can add `editing` boolean the object directly and amend the `v-show="!!msg.editing"` that would be better IMHO, however if that is not possible, I shall update the answer now, for number 2, you can add validators before sending the ajax if the users didnt update the values.

Comment: I've tried doing exactly this, Hamza, but it's not working. I'm posting a separate question for that because it includes more relevant details and a different implementation.

Comment: @zerohedge if you would like, we can join a chat room and finish it

Comment: That would be great. But before, you can have a look at my new question which should give you more details about my issue → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622907/vue-js-html-element-show-if-not-toggling-changes