# vue.js: HTML element show-if not toggling changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm initially rendering some objects from an API call to my database, they are serialized and look like this initially:

```
<h3>Messages on Database</h3>
    <p v-if="messages.length ===0">No Messages</p>
    <div class="msg" v-for="(msg, index) in messages" :key="index">
        <p class="msg-index">[{{index}}]</p>

        <p class="msg-subject" v-html="msg.subject" v-if="!msg.editing"></p>
        <p><input type="text" v-model="msg.subject" v-if="msg.editing" ></p>
        <p>{{msg.editing}}</p>
        <p class="msg-body" v-html="msg.body" v-show="!messages[index].editing"></p>
        <p><input type="text" v-model="msg.body" v-show="messages[index].editing" ></p>

        <input type="submit" @click="deleteMsg(msg.pk)" value="Delete" />
        <input type="submit" @click="EditMsg(index)" value="Edit" />
        <input type="submit" @click="updateMsg(msg.pk)" value="Update" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Messages",
  data() {
    return {
      subject: "",
      msgBody: "",
      messages: [],
    };
```

},

each message looks like this:

[image]

notice that `body`, `pk` and `subject` are the Django model fields. Each item in the array represents a database object.

What I want to do using vue.js, is allow users to edit each item. If the user clicks the `edit` button for an item, I want to transform its element from `p` to `input`, and submit that to the database.

In order to allow editing of **individual** items, I need an `editing` field in each item in the array, so I'm doing this in my `mounted()` property:

```
  mounted() {
    this.fetchMessages();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchMessages() {
      this.$backend.$fetchMessages().then(responseData => {
        this.messages = responseData;
        this.messages.forEach(function (value) {
           value['editing'] = false;
        });
        console.log(this.messages);
      });
    },
```

Now, when I load up the array in my console, I see this:

[image]

So I assumed that now, when the user clicks the `Edit` button, `EditMsg` is called, and the fields will transform according to the `v-if`/`v-show` directives:

```
EditMsg(msgIdx) {
        this.messages[msgIdx].editing = true;
        console.log(this.messages);
    },
```

But that's not happening. What is actually happening is this: the `editing` flag for the item is changed to `true` in the console/vue-developer-tools window, but nothing changes in the HTML.

What am I missing?

Full code:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <img src='@/assets/logo-django.png' style="width: 250px" />
    <p>The data below is added/removed from the Postgres Database using Django's ORM and Restframork.</p>
    <br/>
    <p>Subject</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hello" v-model="subject">
    <p>Message</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="From the other side" v-model="msgBody">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" @click="postMessage" :disabled="!subject || !msgBody">

    <hr/>
    <h3>Messages on Database</h3>
    <p v-if="messages.length ===0">No Messages</p>
    <div class="msg" v-for="(msg, index) in messages" :key="index">
        <p class="msg-index">[{{index}}]</p>

        <p class="msg-subject" v-html="msg.subject" v-if="!msg.editing"></p>
        <p><input type="text" v-model="msg.subject" v-if="msg.editing" ></p>
        <p>{{msg.editing}}</p>
        <p class="msg-body" v-html="msg.body" v-show="!messages[index].editing"></p>
        <p><input type="text" v-model="msg.body" v-show="messages[index].editing" ></p>

        <input type="submit" @click="deleteMsg(msg.pk)" value="Delete" />
        <input type="submit" @click="EditMsg(index)" value="Edit" />
        <input type="submit" @click="updateMsg(msg.pk)" value="Update" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Messages",
  data() {
    return {
      subject: "",
      msgBody: "",
      messages: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchMessages();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchMessages() {
      this.$backend.$fetchMessages().then(responseData => {
        this.messages = responseData;
        this.messages.forEach(function (value) {
           value['editing'] = false;
        });
        console.log(this.messages);
      });
    },
    postMessage() {
      const payload = { subject: this.subject, body: this.msgBody };
      this.$backend.$postMessage(payload).then(() => {
        this.msgBody = "";
        this.subject = "";
        this.fetchMessages();
      });
    },
    deleteMsg(msgId) {
        this.$backend.$deleteMessage(msgId).then(() => {
            this.messages = this.messages.filter(m => m.pk !== msgId);
            this.fetchMessages();
        });
    },
    EditMsg(msgIdx) {
        this.messages[msgIdx].editing = true;
        console.log(this.messages);
    },
    updateMsg(msgId) {
        console.log(this.subject, this.msgBody);
        const payload = { subject: this.subject, body: this.msgBody };
        this.$backend.$putMessage(msgId, payload).then(() => {
            this.fetchMessages();
            }
        )
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
hr {
  max-width: 65%;
}

.msg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.msg-index {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  /* margin-bottom: 0; */
}

img {
  width: 250px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: not sure why this is happening, but check this fiddle it has almost the same code https://jsfiddle.net/ckb34a2r/

Comment: I think it's happening because VueJS doesn't recognize [array mutations through indexing](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/), just not sure how to do my mutation differently. Also, your example works but doesn't apply in my case since I can't do so much boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Vue internals](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Adding_and_Deleting_Properties):

> Vue observes data by converting properties with `Object.defineProperty`. However, in ECMAScript 5 there is no way to detect when a new property is added to an Object, or when a property is deleted from an Object.

So, when you bind your response data to `this.messages`, any mutation to array properties is not considered reactive anymore by Vue.

Instead, if you enrich `responseData` properties before binding it to the Vue data properties, all the array stays reactive. I mean like this:

```
fetchMessages() {
 this.$backend.$fetchMessages().then(responseData => {
        let editableMessages = responseData;
        editableMessages.forEach(function (value) {
           value['editing'] = false;
        });
        this.messages = editableMessages;
      });
}
```

Here there is a [small example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMPxvN) based on your domain.