# vue-i18n: component interpolation with html tags

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

i'm using component interpolation as described [here](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#advanced-usage) but also have some html tags in my translation string for formatting purposes. how should i deal with this?

```
<i18n
    path="description"
    tag="p"
    :places="{ value1, value2, routerLink }"
/>
```

the corresponding key in my .yml file look like:

```
description: Lorem ipsum <nobr><strong>{value1}&#8201;%</strong></nobr> some more text <nobr><strong>{value2}&#8201;%</strong></nobr> and some more text. Go to {routerLink} for more info.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive

```
<i18n
    v-html="description"
    tag="p"
    :places="{ value1, value2, routerLink }"
/>
```

An alternative is can be use a computed that interprets HTML entities [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282349/vuejs-v-model-escape-automatically-html-entities)