# Special characters are displayed as ascii characters in textarea angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Actual string -  • Is Recovery Team assembled? • Critical timing for SLA's - are any impacted now, when will be if incident prolongs?

String getting displayed in textarea - [image]

Please suggest..

HTML code:

```
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">

            <textarea class="form-control form-control-BCC" name="Notes" ng-model="buisnessSaveCommunication.BusinessContinutiydata.KeyMessage" spellcheck="true"></textarea>

        </div>
```

here buisnessSaveCommunication in ng-model is alias.

angularjs :

```
scope.BusinessContinutiydata.KeyMessage = scope.keyMessge;
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @31piy added code in question now. its simple scope value assignment. but in place of apostrophe symbol it is displaying some ascii characters.

Comment: Please add your actual string you are assigning. I mean scope.keyMessage

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya from database only i'm getting this string ""
• Critical timing for SLA&#39;s - are any impacted now, when will be if incident prolongs?""

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya i'm also not able to use $sce.trustAsHtml in textarea.

Comment: So you are getting "Critical timing for SLA&#39;s - are any impacted now, when will be if incident prolongs". My question is, did you get " SLA&#39;s "  from the database or it was being changed when binding to textarea.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya - from database only getting value like this "Critical timing for SLA&#39;s"  - but in database it is stored as "Critical timing for SLA's".

Comment: @PrasadShigwan here you go prasad.. Please find below answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't directly show encoded entities inside `textarea`/`input` box. What you could do is, before binding the value to `textarea` decode it. For the same use `$sanitize` service of `ngSanitize`. Simply passing `html` to `$sanitize` service will return decoded html.

```js
//Make sure you included `ngSanitize` module in your app module dependency
//Also add angular-sanitize.js with the same version that Angularjs has, otherwise it may conflict.
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $sanitize) {
    $scope.test = $sanitize('Critical timing for SLA&#39;s');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <h1>{{test}}!</h1>
</body>
```

---

Otherwise you just need to do manually decoding before binding values to your `textarea`. You can refer [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/2435473) for the same

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYteC/431/)

---

In such cases I'd prefer you to use [**`TextAngular`**](http://textangular.com/) component, which provides similar thing with many additional feature.