# Input element value is rendered as the HTML entity string not the character

Tags: javascript, html

I have many html entities, for example: `&#30906;&#23450;` (Japanese characters), that are being rendered as the string: `&#30906;&#23450;` , not as the characters,
if I try:

var inputEl = document.createElement("input");

inputEl.value = "`&#30906;&#23450;`";

Does anyone know a workaround? I'm a little stumped.

Comment: how about using the text directly in input? [https://jsfiddle.net/xqnk6hma/](https://jsfiddle.net/xqnk6hma/)

Comment: this is probably the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/1244184

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trick. Seems html entities are not decoding properly in your example. Therefore You can use `trick` function to decode them using temporary html `div` element.

```js
function trick(x){
  var a = document.createElement('div');
  a.innerHTML = x;
  return a.innerHTML;
}

var inputEl = document.createElement("input");

inputEl.value = trick("&#30906;&#23450;");

document.getElementById('d').appendChild(inputEl);
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem with this approach is you are introducing an XSS vulnerability if `x` contains executable js.