# Getting course hours from Page Source of Codecademy Catalog page

Tags: json, web-scraping, frontend

**I want to know the estimated hours of the courses which are already started.**

When I do Reset Progress, the course doesn't show the hour instead just changes back to 0%.

[image]

When I check the Page Sourse and look for the hours, I got this.

**What is the below format? JSON? Is there a way to make it readable?**

[image]

Here is a website where some course hours are mentioned, but not all.

https://one-day-resolutions.codecademy.com
[image]

Comment: Try to [decode HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Recommended by a friend, I found [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) extension for Chrome.
- It will appear on the top as a browser extension.
  [image]
- Then I inspect the page, select React tab and use the pointer on the React element I want to inspect.
  [image]
- You can also go to [Codecademy Course Recommendation](https://www.codecademy.com/welcome/find-a-course) for the course hours.