# How to replace the <div>&nbsp;<br></div> with space using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

In the body search all the instances of `<div>&nbsp;<br></div>` and replace with space using JavaScript

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796744/713789

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please familiarize yourself with [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the **[`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method on the `.textContent` of the elements.

You weren't entirely clear as to whether the entire `div` should be replaced or just the `&nbsp;` inside of it. Here are examples dealing with both:

**Replace just the `&nbsp;`:**

```js
// Get all the elements that need work into an array
let elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));

// Loop over the array and replace the HTML entity with a space char.
elements.forEach((el) => { el.textContent = el.textContent.replace("&nbsp;", " "); });
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
```

**Replace the entire `div`:**

```js
let el = document.getElementById("elementToSearch");

// Just replace all occurences of the element with a space
el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace("<div>&nbsp;<br></div>", " ");
```

```css
/* You won't see this style applied anywhere because 
   all the div elements have been removed*/
#elementToSearch div { width:400px; height:100px; background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="elementToSearch">
  <div>&nbsp;<br></div>
  <div>&nbsp;<br></div>
  <div>&nbsp;<br></div>
  <div>&nbsp;<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TylerRoper Did you run the code snippet? It works like a charm.

Comment: You're correct. OP's question is not clear. I was under the impression he wanted to replace the `<div>` entirely, not just the `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Perhaps, but that's not how I interpreted it. Even if that were the case, the same solution would be applicable, albeit with a different *find* string.

Comment: Again, correct, although one could argue about the stance on [answering off topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions). Regardless, your answer seems to be as well as an answer *could* be to this question, so I'll upvote it. **EDIT:** Then again, maybe that link above doesn't apply - this isn't technically *"off-topic"* as much as it's just "bad".

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention that I need it on server side. I would like to replace the tags with space

Comment: current.email_body.replace('<div>&nbsp;<br></div>', ''); is not working. Do I need to add regex expression to achieve it?

Comment: @harshini Are you getting any errors in your Console. The supplied code does work, so if you are having problems, it must be with other parts of your code.

Comment: I didnt get any errors on console. But it is not working as intended

Comment: Can you please suggest me a regex expression to <div>&nbsp;<br></div> and <div><p class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p></div> so that I can use in the replace function?

Comment: You don't need a RegExp, just pass those very strings as the strings to replace.

Comment: It is not working. This should be a problem in setup than code.Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

This example uses straight Javascript.

```js
myDivList = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < myDivList.length; i++) {
  if (myDivList[i].innerHTML == "&nbsp;<br>") {
    myDivList[i].innerHTML = "New value.";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
<div>Not this one.</div>
<div>Not this one.</div>
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
```

Comment: There's no need to post a link to a Fiddle when you've included the identical code snippet right here.

Comment: Thank you @scott-marcus. I was just reading up on how to format posts correctly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm likely to blame for that one. I turned his code into a snippet and didn't remove the fiddle link.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention that I need it on server side. I would like to replace the tags with space

Comment: Are you using a server side JavaScript technology?