# print full path javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

This is the result I am getting from my database when I do a query:

```
[
    {
        "name": "file1.txt",
        "id": 1,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file1.txt"
    }
    {
        "name": "file3.txt",
        "id": 3,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file3.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "file4.txt",
        "id": 8,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file4.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "file5.txt",
        "id": 7,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file5.txt"
    }
]
```

And what I want to print is this kinda of format of file path **./public/files/file1.txt**

This is what I am trying right now but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var paths = [];
if(result.length > 0) {
    var tmp_path = result[0].file_path

    var count = 0

    result.forEach(element =>  {
        count++
        tmp_path = element.file_path
        paths.push(decodeURI(tmp_path))
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(paths,null,4))
}
```

The result I get is this:

```
[
".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file1.txt",
".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file3.txt",
".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file4.txt",
".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file5.txt",
]
```

Isn't decodeURI() the function I am supposed to use in this case?

I am working on Node.js with router and ejs npms. So this is part of a get function and the result will be populated in front-end with ejs. So what I am trying to do is to pass the correct format on the result which is **PATHS**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Voting to close

Comment: @Ivan I will edit so It becomes clear...

Comment: And none of the below answers work?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I am worried that this way in general can't solve the problem and I need a script in front-end (html) to edit the html inside the divs. My thought was that what I return is false but maybe this is the only way a full path can be returned ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decodeURI()` in the following way

```
var uri = ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file1.txt";
var enc = encodeURI(uri);
var dec = decodeURI(enc);
```

You can show this URL in html like below:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dec;
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I wanted to write for an element on html screen. This won't work on console.log

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis mention NodeJS first

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your code so that that file path is saved as a HTML content in a element say, `div` then get the HTML from this element to get the decoded value and push it into the array.

```js
var result = [
    {
        "name": "1k",
        "id": 1,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file1.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "3k",
        "id": 3,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file3.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "4k",
        "id": 8,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file4.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "5k",
        "id": 7,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file5.txt"
    }
];

var paths = [];
if(result.length > 0) {
    var tmp_path = result[0].file_path
    var count = 0
    
    result.forEach(element =>  {
        count++;
        tmp_path = element.file_path;
        var elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.innerHTML = tmp_path;
        paths.push(elem.innerHTML);
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(paths,null,4))
}
```

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis then what are you looking for?

Comment: `And what I want to print is this kinda of format of file path ./public/files/file1.txt` @GerasimosRagavanis isn't this what you asked

Comment: I was about to quote the same line ;)

Comment: I am working on Node.js and paths are part of the result that is being returned to the front-end (which works with ejs so it populates the list). So I don't want to create divs I want to have the proper form in the result I am returning

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis where did you mentioned `Node`? You haven't even tagged the question to `nodejs`

Comment: because it's a javascript question... the result I want is of specific format doesn't matter how I use it. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work for you, but you can use a [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remap the array into an array of strings making slight adjustments:

So for each `file_path` split with `';'` then take the last element of the split `'filei.text'` and concatenate `'./public/files/'` before it.

```
const res = data.map(e => {
  const path = e.file_path.split(';');
  const fileName = path[path.length-1];
  return './public/files/' + fileName;
});
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "1k",
        "id": 1,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file1.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "3k",
        "id": 3,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file3.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "4k",
        "id": 8,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file4.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "5k",
        "id": 7,
        "file_path": ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file5.txt"
    }
];

const res = data.map(e => {
  const path = e.file_path.split(';');
  const fileName = path[path.length-1];
  return './public/files/' + fileName;
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

just encode the `file_path` with [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/encodeURI) you will get original url
e.g.:

```
var uri = ".&#x2F;public&#x2F;files&#x2F;file1.txt";
console.log(encodeURI(uri));
```

Will return:

```
"./public/files/file1.txt"
```