# Convert html decoded string to human readable string in nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I have some strings like this(encoded as utf-8):

`&#x62A;&#x648;&#x633;&#x639;&#x647;`.

I want to convert them to:

توسعه

How can I do that in javascript?

The solution needs to be compatible with ***nashorn***, since I am running the code in a virtual engine in java.

**NOTE:** None of these [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode), [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript) are acceptable for my question, since they do not work in nashorn.

P.S: I have searched for possible solutions, and it was suggested by many to use `decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(yourString)))` (with slight differences), which apparently does not work, as I have tried them in vscode(javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string I mentioned in the question can be broke down to smaller parts separated by `;`. Each part, is a combination of `&#` and a hex number(e.g`x62A`) corresponding to a character(ت).

Following code will do the job, by parsing input `str` and finding corresponding characters. The result is concatenation of characters.

```js
human_readable = function (str) {
            hex_code = str.match(/([^&#]+[\w][^;])|(\s)/g)
            s = ''
            for (j = 0; j < hex_code.length; j++) {
                if (hex_code[j] != ' ') {
                    int_code = parseInt("0" + hex_code[j])
                    char = String.fromCharCode(int_code)
                } else {
                char = ' '
                }
                s = s + char
                }
            return s
        }

console.log(human_readable('&#x62A;&#x648;&#x633;&#x639;&#x647;'))
```

P.S: I have assumed that if str contains white spaces, it will be simply `' '`, and not the corresponding unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear if nashorn supports DOM methods, but typically you can do

```js
var x = '&#x62A;&#x648;&#x633;&#x639;&#x647;'
var y = document.createElement("div")
y.innerHTML = x;
console.log(y.textContent)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work.