# Replace HTML symbols in a string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

From API I receive a string which contains HTML Symbols, example:

```
'Which of these is not a DLC vehicle in &quot;Mario Kart 8&quot;?'
```

Is there a way to parse a string in Javascript/Node.JS so that all these symbols get replaced with normal ones?

[HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode) this question can't help as solutions there are connected with browser-purposed JS

Answer (score -1):

this is answer

```
JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```