# &#039 &quot;It&#039; being rendered in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an API call to: https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10
and getting question and answer data and then rendering them
but instead of symbols, I am getting this `&#039 &quot; It&#039;`

rendering like this

```
export default function Question(props){
    
    return (
        <div className="Question-wrapper">
            <div className="Question--question">{props.question}</div>
            <div className="Question--options">

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Looks like that API html-escapes the values in its JSON… It really shouldn't.

Comment: Just desanitize it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: If you can contact the API creators then you should. It's a mistake on their end to assume that their API results will only ever be used within HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Answer (score -1):

By default, React does not allow create tags from string variables because this is too dangerous. You could use dangerouslysetinnerhtml if it is rly necessary. Please read documentation by this link https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml