# jQuery selector for data attribute array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Theres' this html code:

```
<div class="wcpa_form_outer" data-attrrelated="[&quot;wcpa-select-1658734650073&quot;]">
```

for which i'm trying to append html to it. I have tried various approaches but none have worked.

```
jQuery('.wcpa_form_outer[data-attrrelated="[&quot;wcpa-select-1658734650073&quot;]"]').append('some html here');
```

or

```
jQuery('.wcpa_form_outer[data-attrrelated="[wcpa-select-1658734650073]"]').append('some html here');
```

or

```
jQuery('.wcpa_form_outer').data('attrrelated').append('some html here');
```

any clues?

Comment: The first statement in your question *does* work ...

Comment: @Kooilnc & @ Tibrogargan there was an error in my part in the html. i have updated the original question with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you're using the HTML Entity `&quot;` in your attribute.  This is being translated to a literal quote.  JQuery does not do Entity translation, so it's literally looking for the string `[&quot;wcpa-select-1658734650073&quot;]` with ampersands and all, not `["wcpa-select-1658734650073"]` which is the actual value in your attribute.

You can work around this by using one of the following methods (after also translating the Entity into a quote in your code).

1. Use a CSS "contains" selector for your attribute ( `attr*=value` ) (demonstrated by KooiInc's answer) or
2. Use a string template which will allow you to embed both types of quotes in your string and get an exact match ( `attr=value` ), shown below
3. Constructing a string value containing quotes by using string concatenation (e.g. `'["' + value + '"]'` )
4. Use the `decodeEntities` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/2487517) to translate your attribute value before attempting the lookup (untested, and it's 10 years old)

```js
jQuery(`.wcpa_form_outer[data-attrrelated='["wcpa-select-1658734650073"]']`).append('foo')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wcpa_form_outer" data-attrrelated="[&quot;wcpa-select-1658734650073&quot;]">append here: 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `&quot;` and/or `[]` in the attribute value may be the problem Remove it, or try using a *part* (the most relevant part?) of the attribute value:

```js
$('[data-attrrelated*="1658734650073"]')
  .append('some html here!');
$('[data-attrrelated*="wcpa-select-165873465007"')
  .append('<br>some html here too!');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wcpa_form_outer" data-attrrelated="[&quot;wcpa-select-1658734650073&quot;]"></div>
```