# Are there any methods to convert 'escape sequences' to 'special characters' in the Liquid template language?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid-template

product.type = "100FWTB, 25L-BELOW, 4'4"-5'5", 5'0" - 5'11", FIREWIRE, FUTURES, Groveler Surfboards, HELIUM 2, HELIUM CONSTRUCTION, IN-STOCK, N60, partial_payment, PO#514, SHORTBOARDITEMS, SHORTBOARDS, SURFBOARDS";

"product_type":"{{ product.type | escape }}"

## Here is the result after escape method

`100FWTB, 25L-BELOW, 4&#39;4&quot;-5&#39;5&quot;, 5&#39;0&quot; - 5&#39;11&quot;, FIREWIRE, FUTURES, Groveler Surfboards, HELIUM 2, HELIUM CONSTRUCTION, IN-STOCK, N60, partial_payment, PO#514, SHORTBOARDITEMS, SHORTBOARDS, SURFBOARDS`

And i want to back to noraml in store front

expecting result is

`100FWTB, 25L-BELOW, 4'4"-5'5", 5'0" - 5'11", FIREWIRE, FUTURES, Groveler Surfboards, HELIUM 2, HELIUM CONSTRUCTION, IN-STOCK, N60, partial_payment, PO#514, SHORTBOARDITEMS, SHORTBOARDS, SURFBOARDS`

Comment: What is your question? All your data looks the same. There is nothing going on here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i got the solution from here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182294/14034135